# How to edit the environment variable TEXINPUTS in winedt for adding different search paths?

Tags: windows, winedt, texinputs

I want to edit the environment variable `TEXINPUTS` but I dont know how in windows platform with Winedt. I googled it many times but I didn't get what I need. 
I found how to reach TEXINPUTS by: `> options -> execution modes -> variables`

For example, if I want to add the directory "C:\Texproject" to the directories searched by the LaTeX, what should I type in the blank field of the `TEXINPUTS`?

Comment: Could you please post your solution as an answer (that makes it easier for other people who have the same problem).

Comment: @Caramdir I need what i should type in its field ?!

Comment: I guess you need to enter the search path you want to use? Sorry, without more details it is rather hard to help you.

Comment: @Caramdir: For example, if i want to add the directory "C:\Texproject" to the directories searched by the latex, what should i type in the blank field of the TEXINPUTS ?

Comment: I don't use Windows (and Winedt) and hence are not familiar with it but you could try one of `.:C:\Texproject:$TEXINPUTS`, `.:C:\Texproject` or simply `C:\Texproject`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, Thanks for the support by Caramdir.

After playing there are two ways for adding different search path directories:

**First:**

1- goto options -> execution modes -> variables

2- check on the TEXINPUTS then type in its field (e.g. in case of adding "C:\Texproject"):

- "C:\Texproject" for adding only this directory

OR

- "C:\Texproject//" for adding this directory and its subdirectories

**Second:**

1- goto options -> execution modes -> PATH

2- For the first option "EXTRA PATH FOLDERS", check on "Insert in PATH" then click on the magnifying glass for browsing to any folder you want to add.

3- Select the folder, then click open twice.

The second method only add this directory without its subdirectories.

For the two methods, adding multiple directories is possible by separating each two paths by semicolon.

Waiting for any amendments.

Comment: As this solves your problem, could you accept your own answer here (click on the tick by the answer)?