# \input and absolute paths

Tags: input, paths

Sometimes it is convenient to use an absolute path to include a preamble. To do so, I use the following "hack":

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\newcommand{\folder}{/path/to/folder}
\input{\folder/preamble}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Now my question is, whether there is a more elegant way to do this, especially a way which is compatible with one of the flatten scripts from [Replace \input{fileX} by the content of fileX automatically](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21838/replace-inputfilex-by-the-content-of-filex-automatically) ?

Answer (score 46):

You can define the internal macro `\input@path` to hold a list of base directories:

```
\makeatletter
\def\input@path{{/path/to/folder/}}
%or: \def\input@path{{/path/to/folder/}{/path/to/other/folder/}}
\makeatother
```

Then you can use `\input{fileinthatfolder}` everywhere. It also works for `\includegraphics` IIRC.

But I don't think this is supported by the mentioned scripts. AFAIK they simply take the string from the file and don't look at any macros.

Comment: So this is basically `\graphicspath` but for `\input`? Neat.

Comment: @Seamus: actually `\graphicspath` defaults to the value of `\input@path` at package load time. Then inside `\includegraphics` inside a group `\input@path` is set to the `\graphicspath` value. However, there might be some tools which don't take `\input@path` into account. IIRC it is better to use the TEXINPUTS environment variable. But you can't set them inside the document.

Comment: I actually just changed my answer to offer the TEXINPUTS as a possible solution! Great minds...

Comment: In case anyone else is running into problems with this answer:
I am trying to use PDFLaTeX on an ubuntu machine with texlive. If I use `/path/to/folder` instead of `/path/to/folder/` I get a problem. However with `/path/to/folder/` things run smoothly. Thanks!

Comment: I had the same experience.  The final slash seems to be mandatory.  Maybe someone can edit the answer?

Comment: @jan, Jeremy: Thanks, I added the trailing slashes now.

Comment: It does not seem to work for bib files included by doing `\bibliography{myfile.bib}`, using the `biblatex` package.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent: `biblatex` might use plainTeX original `\input` (redefined as `\@@input` by LaTeX) or LaTeX3 and not the normal LaTeX `\input` macro.

Answer (score 24):

So I had one answer (which is preserved below for posterity) but I think I understand the question a little better now. What you want is to write `\input{foo}` and have LaTeX know where to search for `foo`. Martin's answer offers one way to do this. Here are some others.

One way is to make a directory in your local texmf tree and put files you want to use in there. So (assuming a uni system) this will be something like `~/texmf/` Make a subdirectory e.g. `~/texmf/tex/latex/commonstuff/` and put your files in there. Then they will be available to `\input`. Be careful about name clashes, though!

If, for whatever reason, you cannot move where your files are stored, you could add that directory to `TEXINPUTS` which is a variable that stores the directories that tex searches for files called with `\usepackage` `\input` and similar commands.

Further reading:

- [Where do I place my own .sty files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-tex-files)
- [LaTeX environment variables (PDF)](http://www2.ph.ed.ac.uk/~wjh/tex/documents/environmental.pdf)
- [How to edit the environment variable TEXINPUTS in winedt for adding different search paths ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6528/how-to-edit-the-environment-variable-texinputs-in-winedt-for-adding-different-sea)

I maintain that this may be overkill if the problem is simply that some files live in the folder "above" the one containing the tex file (when the `../` trick discussed below works fine)

---

I don't really understand the question. As far as I am aware, absolute paths work with `\input`? I just tried one and it worked.

Sometimes it is easier to use relative paths, but to know how to use them. For example a lot of the time I want to insert a graphic which is housed in a different folder. Let's say I have the following:

```
Work
  Document
    main.tex
  Graphics
    img.pdf
```

In `main.tex` I can write `\includegraphics{../Graphics/img}` and this finds my image: `..` goes "up a level".

Comment: Could whoever downvoted this explain why? Thanks.

Comment: Whoever downvoted seems happy with the new answer... I'd still appreciate an explanation of what was faulty with the earlier answer...

Answer (score 5):

An other solution (easiest) is given by Ali Mehrizi in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60135/path-to-external-files-in-nested-input).

The solution is based on the `import` package, using the `subimport` command:

```
\subimport{PathToFolder/}{File.tex}.
```

A later `\input{}` into the "File" will search for a file into the specified folder `PathToFolder/`.

Comment: While this does not quite seem to answer the question, the information itself was very helpful in solving a slightly different problem: how to organize a large document with a subdirectory structure. See also: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4602/8057

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you're satisfied with this:
Just do a symbolic link of the file you want to include into the directory of the file you want to compile and use \input{preamble}.
(This might not work anywhere else than Linux)

Comment: Thanks, but that's not an option for me. Suppose the preamble file is in a folder foo. Now I have a rather large directory tree under foo, where in every subfolder there could be a tex file which wants to include the preamble. Using emacs auto-insert, emacs inserts the include line for the preamble automatically if I create a tex file in some folder of that tree. So using a symbolic link would be not very convenient since then I have to create one for every folder of my tree and a new one for every new folder...

Comment: This is a very bad idea indeed! Besides not being OS portable, it does not work with folder under other tools, like for example `Dropbox` which does allow for sym links withing their directories.

Comment: It works well with Nextcloud and git though. (I mean, you'd hopefully not share a LaTeX project via Dropbox anyways.) OS portability is a problem, yes, if you work with Windows (users).