# Filenames accessible from different directories

Tags: input, paths

I have a directory structure with following directories (upper-cased) and files as follows:

```
Main Folder
masterfile.tex
  Chapter
  content.tex
  tempfile.tex
    Figures
    figure1.pdf
```

All the text of my document is in `content.tex`, though it includes the graphic `figure1.pdf`. Both the `masterfile.tex` and `tempfile.tex` input `content.tex`. In `masterfile.tex`, I use `\input{Chapter/content}`; in `tempfile.tex`, I use `\input{content}`.

How do I properly reference `figure1.pdf` within `content.tex`?

If I use `\includegraphics{figure1}`, then neither `masterfile.tex` nor `tempfile.tex` can find it.

If I use `\includegraphics{Figures/figure1}`, then `tempfile.tex` can find it, though `masterfile.tex` can't.

If I use `\includegraphics{Chapter/Figures/figure1}`, then `tempfile.tex` can't find it, though `masterfile.tex` can.

I can't seem to find the right relative pathname to make it work. Martin's solution to [this problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21904/input-and-absolute-paths) seems applicable, but I can't make that work, either.

Yes, I know one solution is to change to location of my files, but let's just say that can't be done.

Comment: Maybe i do not understand the question/structure right, but does simply `\includegraphics{Figures/figure1.pdf}` work?

Comment: the filenames are relative to your working directory so should work if you always from latex from `main Folder` but perhaps simpler is not to put paths in the commands and just use `\input{content}` and `\includegraphics{figure1}`

Comment: @Bobyandbob Since the `Figures` folder is within the `Chapter` folder, using just `\includegraphics{Figures/figure1.pdf}` isn't found when I compile `masterfile.tex`, though it is found when compiling `tempfile.tex`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That doesn't seem to work ... with the images one or two directories down, LaTeX doesn't seem to be able to find them. Is there an option for "search all subdirectories"?

Comment: yes just put .// in your TEXINPUTS path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my own problem after more searching. (While I didn't try it, David Carlisle's answer works, I'm sure. In my situation, though, I am one of many editing/compiling the same documents, and asking all of my colleagues to edit their TEXINPUTS path wouldn't have turned out well.)

In `content.tex`, I use `\includegraphics{Chapter/Figures/figure1}` which allows `masterfile.tex` to compile just fine. In the preamble of `tempfile.tex`, I add `\graphicspath{{../../Main Folder/}}`, which is the start of an acceptable relative path for that file.