# Inkscape saving pdfs without the path

Tags: graphics, paths, inkscape, folders

I'd like to know why and if someone knows a solution about saving pdf + latex gives the wrong path to the tex file.

So for instance:

If I save an svg inside mainfolder/subfolder as pdf with omit text.. Latex, it will save the `\input..{filename.pdf_tex}` without the subfolder, so instead of saving it as `\input..{subfolder/filename.pdf_tex}`.

That leaves me adding the subfolder every time, manually. Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Inkscape itself cannot know in which .tex file you want to include the image nor where the main .tex file is located. So it can just add all the information is has, which is the file name.

---

Workaround:

If `filename.pdf_tex` is in a location which is automatically searched by latex, you don't need to add the path and just include it with `\input{filename.pdf_tex}`. Possibles locations for this:

- Your main folder, but you probably don't want to clutter it, if you are using a subfolder now ...
- add the subfolder to `\input@path`, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24827/36296
- you could add the subfolder to your TEXINPUTS , see e.g. [Definition of the TEXINPUTS variable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93712/definition-of-the-texinputs-variable)
- your texmf folder
- ...

Comment: I honestly can't understand what I need to do to add the subfolder to TEXINPUTS, would you explain it easily?

Comment: This would be the solution which your refer to when you talk about "automatically searched by latex", right?

Comment: @user9613078 If you are not familiar with setting environment variables, I suggest to first try with the `\input@path`. Add something like `\makeatletter
\providecommand*{\input@path}{}
\g@addto@macro\input@path{{subfolder//}}
\makeatother
` to your preamble

Comment: @user9613078 If you'd rather go the TEXINPUTS route, it would be helpful to know which operating system you use and which shell type you have.

Comment: Ubuntu 17.10, with gnome shell type

Comment: @user9613078 To add the subfolder to TEXINPUTS try to enter something like `export TEXINPUTS=.:/home/path/to/the/subfolder//:` in the terminal. This will change it for the current terminal session. If it works, you could permanently adjust it by adding it to your `.profile` or `.bash_rc` or `.bash_profile` (whichever you are using...)

Comment: And if I wanna do that with multiple subfolders, I would need to add every time export.. To the bashrc? What I mean is every time I make a mainfolder and a subfolder, I would need to add the subfolder path to bashrc? Can't I say every time I make a folder with a subfolder called images consider it as a path?

Comment: @user9613078 If you set TEXINPUTS to `:.//` it will search all subfolders of your current folder

Comment: Solved! with \graphicspath{{subfolder/}} in the preamble and inside the document with \input{subfolder/filename.pdf_tex}

Answer (score 1):

Solved! with `\graphicspath{{subfolder/}}` in the preamble and inside the document with `\input{subfolder/filename.pdf_tex}`.

Source here: http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/info/svg-inkscape/InkscapePDFLaTeX.pdf