# Python cannot compile LaTeX file

Tags: xetex, python

I am using a **Conda** *Python* installation and **Jupyter** to work with a script producing a LaTeX file I want to compile. These are the relevant code lines:

```
import subprocess
xelatex= "/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-darwin/xelatex"
subprocess.check_call([xelatex, '-shell-escape', '-file-line-error', '-interaction=nonstopmode', '-synctex=1', my_folder+'/output_file.tex'])
```

Unfortunately, *the LaTeX source file does not get compiled* and Python returns a non-zero exit status along the following lines:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CalledProcessError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-fc4edbf90d41> in <module>
      1 import subprocess
      2 xelatex= "/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-darwin/xelatex"
----> 3 subprocess.check_call([xelatex, '-shell-escape', '-file-line-error', '-interaction=nonstopmode', '-synctex=1', dir_AED+'/registro_lezioni.tex'])

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py in check_call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
    289         if cmd is None:
    290             cmd = popenargs[0]
--> 291         raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    292     return 0
    293 

CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-darwin/xelatex', '-shell-escape', '-file-line-error', '-interaction=nonstopmode', '-synctex=1', 'my_folder+'/output_file.tex']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

I have a **Tex Live 2018** installation on my Mac that works smoothly with many other apps:

```
Last login: Sat Nov  3 07:39:44 on ttys000
Restored session: Sat Nov  3 07:33:30 CET 2018MacBook-Pro:~ m*****$ xelatex
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99999 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=xelatex) restricted \write18 enabled.
**
```

Using any other LaTeX-based app, like Texpad, *the source file gets compiled with no errors*. I went to the Conda terminal window and the problem seems to be that the LaTeX compiler cannot find a ancillary file:

```
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translator/translator-basic-dicti
onary-English.dict)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/siunitx/siunitx-abbreviations.cfg
) (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/wasysym/uwasy.fd)

! LaTeX Error: File `fragment.tex' not found.
```

Nevertheless, the file **fragment.tex** does live in the same folder, but the LaTeX compiler cannot find it.

In sum, *I need to instruct the LaTeX compiler to look for files in the same folder where the main source file is located*.

Comment: @Grimler, I can hardly understand why your raised these points since:
(1) I wrote that **"the file fragment.tex does live in the same folder,"**
(2) I also added that using Texpad **"the source file gets compiled with no errors."**
(3) To state it again: **the main source file and the fragment are in the same directory.**
(4) The problem **is totally related** to how the Python compiler is being called by Python.

Comment: Ah, right, you wrote that you got the `LaTeX Error: File `fragment.tex' not found.`-error in the terminal window, not from texpad, my bad

Comment: tex relative paths are relative to the working directory from where the program was started, not the directory of the main file. can you get python to do `cd foo; xeletex file` instead of `xelatex foo/file` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks so much! I have just changed the working directory and the LaTeX file now gets compiled. If I remember correctly, one can also pass the required folder as an additional argument to the **subprocess.check_call** command, right?

Comment: @Valerio I can tell you about the tex, not the python:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tex relative paths are relative to the working directory from where the program was started, not the directory of the main file. can you get python to do

```
cd foo; xeletex file
```

instead of

```
xelatex foo/file
```

?

Answer (score 1):

So I guess you get the error because you are compiling from the parent of the texfile when using python/conda, but from the texfile directory in texpad.

You could either set the TEXINPUTS environment variable to make xelatex search in custom directories (see [\input and absolute paths](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21904/input-and-absolute-paths)), or change your include command to the full (or relative path) to fragment.tex.

I don't know how you're including fragment.tex but this means for example changing `\input{fragment}` to `\input{dir_AED/fragment}`