# Is there a way to add a directory to the search path on the fly / not redefine?

Tags: input, paths, nesting

Numerous examples (see [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21904/input-and-absolute-paths) for instance) describe the the use of:

```
\makeatletter
\def\input@path{%
{<path1>}%
{<path2>}%
}%
\makeatother
```

as way to broaden the compiler's search universe when externalized content is called via `\input{}` and the argument to `\input{}` lacks an explicit relative or absolute path.

In a project which involves moderate nesting (e.g. 3 or 4 levels), it's seeming as though it would be beneficial to be able to add (and possibly remove) paths from this path list.

Is this possible?

Comment: You can do this easily in expl3, if that's an option. If you're careful, you can presumably do the same thing with `\input@path` by saving the value to `\input@oldpath` and then using it to define `\input@path`. In the former case, you need to use expl3 functions rather than `\input`, but it is straightforward to create a wrapper e.g. `\xinput` for document-level use. I use this a lot. It broke recently, but Joseph Wright had it fixed in less than no time.

Comment: I wouldn't normally use `\input@path` (and I implemented it:-) it is much more efficient to set the input path in the environment, `TEXINPUTS=path1//:path2//: pdflatex myfile`  will search all directories below path1, then all directories below path2 then all the standard places

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It isn't more efficient if LaTeX gets to page 343 before failing to find a file because you forgot this one needed so-and-so path added :(. Generally, if I have to add it on the command line, I'll forget. If I can put it in the file, it's more efficient even if it wouldn't be more efficient if I didn't forget.

Comment: it doesn't have to be on the commandline every time, you can put it in the environment setup or in a texmf.cnf file, but if you want the macro it is there, you don't need any special commands you can just define it or redefine it using `\def` or `\renewcommand` at any point in the document. so if each chapter wants its own path, just define it at the start of each chapter.