# Path to External Files in Nested \input

Tags: input

### Problem

I usually load a helping TeX file that contains my customizations, e.g., usual packages, corporate standard colors, and macros for abbreviations. I want my helping file to also load another external file that is in the same folder. I certainly want to avoid giving the explicit path to the second external file every time.

### Example

Let's say the helping file is `cosmetix.tex`, which loads `abbreviations.tex`. `abbreviations.tex` is in the same folder as `cosmetix.tex` and both are in a folder called `common`:

```
% cosmetix.tex
% ... some customization
% load abbreviations
\input{abbreviations.tex}
```

My main file is `tester.tex`:

```
% tester.tex
\documentclass{article}

% load cosmetix
\input{common/cosmetix.tex}

\begin{document}
Dummy text.
\end{document}
```

This leads to the following error: LaTeX error: File `abbreviations.tex' not found.

### Question

How can I use nested `\input`s with files in different folders without (i) converting my code to a package and (ii) using absolute paths?

### Context

Although this question is pretty generic, it is also a follow up to my previous question: [Reproducing an official letterhead](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59932/reproducing-an-official-letterhead/). I have reproduced my institute's letterhead, which in turn needs to load the logo. I load the letterhead using the `\input` mechanism. I know this is not the most elegant way, but until I get time to convert this to a package (or read `scrlttr2` documentation to convert my letterhead to an option file), this is a solution that reasonably works for me.

As I mentioned above, I can't use absolute paths because I'm using multiple computers with different operating systems, and therefore, the root of the directory tree is different for each computer.

Comment: I always use relative paths, so something like `../common/` (with as many `../` needed to get to a common point) assuming that you keep all the files at the same hierarchy depth. Otherwise you could define a `\Path` which has the full path and use `\input{\Path/common/<file>}`.

Comment: @PeterGrill, that's how I do it too---a macro containing *relative* path and pass it to the helper file. But if the files are in the same folder, shouldn't this make my life easier?

Comment: You can add the helper files to your local TeX common folder, e.g., `~/texmf/tex/latex/commons`. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1167/9626 by @JosephWright

Comment: @AliMehrizi, yes, I could, but if I didn't use Dropbox to sync my files across different computers or if Dropbox let me use a second folder to share.

Comment: @AliMehrizi, hmm, you only marginally mentioned that in your question, but now I see it. How about updating TEXINPUTS on your computers? See, e.g., http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6528/how-to-edit-the-environment-variable-texinputs-in-winedt-for-adding-different-se

Comment: @AliMehrizi, now that works. Still not the best solution, but could you please add it as an "answer"?

Comment: @AliMehrizi, just found a better solution. Use package `import`, which is written exactly to serve this purpose.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use the package `import`, which does exactly one thing: to solve this problem. See

> http://www.ctan.org/pkg/import

Basically the package defines two commands: `\import` and `\subimport`. `\import` needs an absolute path, while `subimport` needs a relative path. They both look at the current folder and `TEXINPUTS` first. If you want to avoid checking `TEXINPUTS`, use the starred version.

**Example**

For your case, the only line you need to change is to update `\input` to use `\subimport` (and of course, add `\usepackage{import}`). That is, you would need to write:

```
\subimport{common}{cosmetix.tex}
```

No changes are necessary in `cosmetix.tex`.

Comment: does anyone know if import can be nested, i.e., `\import{myDir/}{myfile}` and in myfile.tex have `\import{./figures/}{myFig.tikz}`?

Comment: @daaxix, yes, it can.

Comment: I was having this exact problem, and ended up here. I was disappointed that it seems nothing on this page explains *why* it's happening. While reading I kept tweaking things, and I think I know what's going on. While compiling the main document, it interprets the relative path from the location of the main tex file. If all projects folders have the same relative path to the common folder, you can write `cosmetix.tex` to input the other file as if it's in a project file. In my case, this won't work, since I have subprojects. I look forward to trying out `import`.

Comment: could one replicate this with \subfile ?

Comment: I was going mad because it wanted: \subimport{common\}{cosmetix.tex} intstead of \subimport{common}{cosmetix.tex}

Answer (score 9):

I personally try to avoid having to remember to change settings just because I switched computers.  And since you are using Dropbox, I would recommend you set up your directory structure so that it is portable and does not require special settings:

```
 /Projects
     common/
     paper1/
     paper2/
```

Don't keep files in the `\Projetcs` directory, but only in the sub-directories, and always use relative paths:

```
\newcommand*{\CommonPath}{../commom}% 
\input{CommonPath/abbreviations.tex}%
```

Alternatively, you could adapt one of the solutions from [How to detect and condition based on hostname](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30617/how-to-detect-and-condition-based-on-hostname/) to define a different root path depending on which machine you are on.

Comment: in fact my directory structure is already similar to what you mentioned, but with the addition that my root also has a (for example) `Proposals` folder in which subfolder `proposal1` also needs to call something from `common`. Your solution of giving path as a macro would work if I use `\CommonPath` in both the main file and the helper file.

Comment: This can work if you define \CommonPath in each file.  So /Projects/paper1/Paper1.tex would define it as `../common` and /Projects/Proposals/proposal1/Proposal1.tex would define it as `../../common`.  It is a bit klunky and repetitive, but there is minimal duplication.

Comment: @TroyDaniels: I would have the `\newcommand*{\CommonPath}{../commom}` in a custom `.sty` file that all the files include via `\usepacakge{}`.

Comment: @PeterGrill A common file does not work in this case, because his directory structure is such that sometimes `CommonPath` is `../common` and sometimes it is `../../common`.

Answer (score 4):

As discussed in comments on the question, it seems a reasonable solution is to update the `TEXINPUTS` variable. You will have to update this variable on all of your computers. If you are using Dropbox or any sync software to keep your computers in sync, you should put the common folder in their path.

For WindEdt/Win7, Choose `Variables` tab from `Options | Execution Modes`. Under `TEXINPUTS` variable (or add it if it's not there) enter the absolute path to the folder. The screen shot below shows how when the common folder is called `_Common`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well I think it is, because input just puts the commands of the file in as is. So the whole file `tester.tex` would look like

```
% tester.tex
\documentclass{article}

% load cosmetix
% cosmetix.tex
% ... some customization
% load abbreviations
\input{abbreviations.tex}

\begin{document}
Dummy text.
\end{document}
```

That will be compiled. Since you are in the folder of `tester.tex` it cannot load `abbreviations.tex`. You would need to put `\input{common/abbreviations.tex}` into `cosmetix.tex`.