# Alternative to import package for other commands that include external files

Tags: verbatim, import

The `import` package, specifically its `subimport` command, makes it possible to input another file while specifying a base directory, so that all further `\inputs` in the included file will be resolved relative to the specified base directory. See for instance [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60227).

However, the `import` package does not work for other commands than `\input` which include external files. For instance, it does not work with the `VerbatimInput` command from the `verbatim` package

Is there a workaround or another package that `import` which would work better for this use case?

Comment: If you solved the problem in some way, please provide an answer; otherwise, please try giving some more information.