# Can a default path be set globally for \input{...} akin to \graphicspath{...}?

Tags: input, paths

For the `graphicx` package, we can use `\graphicspath{...}` so that we can directly use filenames in the argument of `\includegraphics{...}`. Can a similar thing be done for directly using filenames in `\input{...}`. I know of the method mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60147/21353) but if this was the way to do it, then why does `\graphicspath{...}` exist?

Comment: Related: [How to make the main file recognize relative paths used in the imported files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4602) (Take a look at [Andrew's comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4602/how-to-make-the-main-file-recognize-relative-paths-used-in-the-imported-files#comment6829_4602) as well.)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

`\graphicspath` comes from LaTeX's `\input@path`, just using the paths for graphics files.
`\input@path` can be set independently, e.g.:

```
\makeatletter
\def\input@path{{path1/}{path2/}}
\makeatother
```

Internally package `graphics` stores its path of `\graphicspath` in `\Ginput@path` and
locally sets `\input@path` to `\Ginput@path`, if it looks for files via `\IfFileExists`.

### Addition to `\input@path`

The macro `\input@path` can be undefined (usually the default in LaTeX) or it can already contain other path entries. Therefore, `\providecommand` in the following code first defines the macro for the case that `\input@path` is undefined. Then `\g@addto@macro` extends the definition of `\input@path`.

```
\makeatletter
\providecommand*{\input@path}{}
\g@addto@macro\input@path{{path1/}{path2/}}% append
\makeatother
```

Alternatively `\edef` can be used, which expands the definition text. 
The next example uses it to prepend the contents to `\input@path` to the old meaning of `\input@path`:

```
\makeatletter
\providecommand*{\input@path}{}
\edef\input@path{{path1/}{path2/}\input@path}% prepend
\makeatother
```

Comment: how do you *add* to that list without removing whatever is there already?

Comment: @FrederickNord Answer updated for showing how to append or prepend new path elements.

Comment: This works great! I sometimes compile .tex files directly other times from a makefile in another folder. Using this method automatically adjusts the locations of figures and .bib files for each of these eventualities.

Answer (score -3):

You can try this:

```
\graphicspath{{figures/}{logs/}}
```

It must have two items, like figures and logs.
Besides, it must have `/` after the item.

Try it!

Comment: Does this really apply specifically to `\input`?  My understanding is that this will still apply only to graphics, not to other files.