# Including figures relative to the path of the current document?

Tags: graphics, input, standalone, import

I am writing a paper simultaneously with my thesis; the paper will be included verbatim in the thesis (or at least, parts of it will).

I am looking for a solution that allows me to update my paper without maintaining a separate version for inclusion in the thesis.

I currently use the `standalone` package with the `import` package to allow inclusion of independently-compilable documents.  This works for almost everything, but not for figures:  I include figures with `\includegraphics`, and it cannot find figures included in a subdirectory of the *paper* unless they're also in the same subdirectory of the *thesis*.

Is there a way around this, besides the obvious but, imo, ugly use of symbolic links?

---

Following the suggested links, I noted that this question: [How to make the main file recognize relative paths used in the imported files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4602/how-to-make-the-main-file-recognize-relative-paths-used-in-the-imported-files) recommends using subimport, in which case my question may become "when should I use `subimport` vs `import` vs `input`."  But I'm not sure, so I'm still asking the original question, this is just "showing my work".

Comment: Related question: In addition to the solutions below, all answers in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79058/250119 should also work here.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Latex actually supports to use relative paths. Both of the following two ways can achieve your goal (assume all your figures in `figures` folder):

1. Add `\graphicspath {{figures/}}` before `\begin{document}`
2. Use `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/your-figure.eps}`