# On TEXINPUTS, input@path, graphicspath, l_file_search_path_seq etc

Tags: macros, tex-core, external-files

There appears to [be](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103008/including-figures-relative-to-the-path-of-the-current-document) [multiple](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4602/how-to-make-the-main-file-recognize-relative-paths-used-in-the-imported-files) [methods](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93712/definition-of-the-texinputs-variable?noredirect=1&lq=1) to customize the locations where (La)TeX search for files, as well as packages like `import` etc.

- What are they/how to use them?
- Why were they introduced? Why are there so many options?
- What's the difference between them?
- What commands do they affect? (e.g. `\input \include \@@input \openin \includegraphics \includepdf \lstinputlisting \VerbatimInput` etc.)