# How to specify a source directory for images and chapter files?

Tags: external-files

I am doing a Thesis report in a modular fashion which includes a lot of different pictures and several chapters.

I figured out how to specify a source directory for all my images

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./ImageDatabase/}}
```

My current dilemma is, how to the same for tex files?

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of [Can a default path be set globally for \input{...} akin to \graphicspath{...}?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79058)

Comment: Sorry for the redundancy. I was playing with the wrong keywords in the search I guess. Thanks anyways for pointing me to some previous answers. Let me try my luck there.