# How to use \graphicspath?

Tags: graphics, miktex, texlive

I am using MikTex 2.9 and TeXstudio for my TeX preparation. I would like to set the path to my `figures` folder, which contains all the figures, plots etc. required for my work.

I used `\graphicspath` to set the directory, but it gives me an error message:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\graphicspath{D:/LATEX/Reports@IIT/figures}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=4.5cm,height=4cm,angle=0]{logo.jpg}

\end{document}
```

> Error: Package pdftex.def Error: File `logo.jpg' not found

However, when I prepend the filenames of the images with the same path in the `\includegraphics` command, it works just fine:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=4.5cm,height=4cm,angle=0]{D:/LATEX/Reports@IIT/figures/logo.jpg}

\end{document}
```

Why is `\graphicspath` not setting the path?

Comment: What happen if you add `/` after `figures` in `graphicspath`?

Comment: @Marienplatz It's a windows machine and paths are system dependent. If somebody else needs a windows solution miktex is a viable option.

Comment: @percusse But `\graphicspath` works the same irrespective of platform

Comment: @JosephWright Also true. But that's not people search unfortunately, including me. Added TeXLive too so hopefully both can end up here.

Comment: I think it's important to understand that this feature is not that sophisticated and it is on the programmer's reconnaissance to use it sensibly. If in the OP example, the path, as typed, was correctly inside its own set of brackets, which is essential, the code would work if the file name was typed in as `\logo.jpg`. The file name is simply being appended to the path, so if both are weird, but together make a sensible path name, it will work. If the graphics path _was_ terminated by `/` you could also access subfolders in your graphics stash with `Subfolder/logo.jpg`.

Answer (score 285, accepted):

```
\graphicspath{{D:/LATEX/Reports@IIT/figures/}}
```

Try it!

More general case:

```
\graphicspath{{subdir1/}{subdir2/}{subdir3/}...{subdirn/}}
```

The `...` is not the part of the syntax for sure! It is there just to represent something like `1,2,3,...,n` in a set theory.

If the figures are saved in a sibling directory, use `../` to access the parent directory.

```
    \graphicspath{{../figs/}}
```

Comment: I often find this useful: `\graphicspath{{./figs/}}`  This will include a subdirectory named `figs` which is in the same directory as your current .tex file

Comment: I have found that the pathnames enclosed in braces must not have any spaces in them.

Comment: Just visiting but to put upvoting :))

Answer (score 84):

Every specific path shoud be ended by `/`, and contained by a pair of braces. Try:

```
\graphicspath{{D:/LATEX/Reports@IIT/figures/}}
```

Comment: By the way...is there an option to organise videos in a diferent directory, as well as we did with our graphics? Thx

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79060/36296