# Errors when trying to insert graphics file

Tags: graphics, errors

I want to include a graphics called quadratic.pdf in my LaTeX document, which only contains the image show below.

While compiling, I get the following errors:

```
Line 1: Fatal Error No output file produced 

Line 5: !LaTeX error. File: 'quadratic.pdf.sty' not found.
```

Where am I going wrong?

[image: Quadratic.pdf]

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{quadratic.pdf}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Basic Graphics}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{quadratic}
\caption{The graphics file named \texttt{quadratic}.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Remove `\usepackage{quadratic.pdf}` (`\usepackage` is a macro for loading LaTeX packages, not for inserting images) and make sure `quadratic.pdf` is the same folder as your `tex` file.

Comment: Thank you @jubobs it works.. Yayyy !! :) Daleif the pdf was on desktop and .tex in another folder. I didn't knew. Thanks Anyways :)

Comment: @Abi Cool. To keep things tidy, you may also want to store your graphics in some subfolder (e.g. `./graphics/`) of the folder containing your `tex` file. Look up [`\graphicspath`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139401/how-to-use-graphicspath) for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Too long as a comment.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
%\graphicspath{{./}{./SubdirOne/}{./SubdirTwo/}<... more items here ...>{./SubdirOne/SubsubdirOne/}}
\graphicspath{{./}{./SubdirOne/}{./SubdirTwo/}}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Basic Graphics}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{quadratic}
\caption{The graphics file named \texttt{quadratic}.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```