# No PDF file found

Tags: pdftex, miktex, texstudio, windows

I am using TeXStudio and MikTex 2.9 (Windows 10).
My file was working properly until today and I did not change anything.
I've already tried renaming the file and change permissions (allow all changes) in the MikTex folder.
The error that appears is:
I can't write on file `tesis.pdf'. \includegraphics[width=4cm]{logo}
Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openright,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{vmargin}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{float}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\fancypagestyle{chapterfirstpage}{%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}%
\fancyhf{}%
\rfoot{\thepage}%
}
\xpatchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{chapterfirstpage}}{\typeout{Success}}{\typeout{Failed}}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\newcommand\blankpage{%
\null
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\addtocounter{page}{-1}%
\newpage}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % para que ponga 1.1.1.1..
 \setcounter{tocdepth}{3} % para que añadir las secciones en el índice...
 \usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \graphicspath{{./figuras/}}
 \usepackage{setspace}
 \usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=chem-angew,citestyle=numeric-comp,sorting=none,]{biblatex}
 \addbibresource{biblio} 
 \usepackage{csquotes}
  \usepackage{titlesec}
 \usepackage{tocloft}
 \usepackage{tabu}
 \titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\huge\sffamily}{\thechapter.}{0.1em}{\Huge}
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{.}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
 \makeindex
 \usepackage{acronym}%[acronym, toc, nonumberlist, shortcuts, xindy=language=spanish-traditional, sanitize=none]{glossaries}
 \usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
 \raggedbottom
\begin{document}
 \doublespacing
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Lista de Tablas}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Lista de Figuras}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Índice}
\renewcommand{\glossaryname}{Lista de Acrónimos}

\include{./capitulos/titulo2}
\include{./capitulos/ded}
\include{./capitulos/resumenes}
\include{./capitulos/abst}
\clearpage
\include{./capitulos/tabla}
\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Lista de figuras} % para que aparezca en el indice de contenidos
\listoffigures
\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Lista de tablas} % para que aparezca en el indice de contenidos
\listoftables
\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Lista de Acrónimos}
\include{./capitulos/listas}
\include{./capitulos/tablatlista}
\clearpage
\include{./capitulos/acronyms}
\clearpage
 \include{./capitulos/introduccion}
\include{./capitulos/Materialesm}
\include{./capitulos/sintesis}
\include{./capitulos/SBR}
\include{./capitulos/pvdf}
\include{./capitulos/gracias}
\include{./capitulos/bibliog}
 \end{document}
```

I know it has lots of `\include` but when I tried to copy the chapter where the error appears, it worked properly. Here I copy what I have in the chapter "titulo2", where I got the error:

```
\sffamily
\begin{titlepage}

\begin{center}
    \vspace*{-1in}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
            \includegraphics[width=4cm]{logo}
    \end{figure}

    Facultad de Ciencias Exactas y Naturales\\
    \vspace*{0.15in}
    Departamento de Química Inorgánica, Analítica y Química Física \\
    \vspace*{0.1in}


    \begin{Large}
        \textbf{Materiales Multiferroicos: síntesis, caracterización y aplicación al desarrollo de dispositivos magneto-eléctricos} \\
    \end{Large}
    \vspace*{0.1in}
    \begin{large}
    Tesis presentada para optar por el título de Doctor de la Universidad de Buenos Aires en el área Química Inorgánica, Analítica y Química Física\\
    \vspace{0.05in}
    \rule{80mm}{0.1mm}\\
    \textbf{Lic}\\
    \end{large}
    \vspace*{0.1in}
    \begin{large}
    Director: \\
        \textbf{i} \\ 
        \vspace{0.1in}
        Consejera de Estudios:\\
        \textbf{s}\\
        \vspace{0.1in}
        Lugar de trabajo:\\
        \textbf{Departamento }\\
        Buenos Aires, 201\\
        \vspace{0.1in}
    Fecha de defensa:
    \end{large}
\end{center}

\end{titlepage}
```

Here I add the complete error message:
      This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2015.3.16)  25 MAR 2016 22:28
     entering extended mode
     bravenewworld.tex
     (bravenewworld.tex
      LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
      Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 68 languages loaded.
     ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\base\book.cls"
      Document Class: book 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
     ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\base\bk10.clo"
     File: bk10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)

```
  ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\emptypage\emptypage.sty"
 Package: emptypage 2010/05/30 v1.2 Suppress page numbers and headings on           empty 
 pages
 )
  ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\xpatch\xpatch.sty"
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\l3kernel\expl3.sty"
 Package: expl3 2015/03/01 v5547 L3 programming layer (loader) 
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\l3kernel\expl3-code.tex"
 Package: expl3 2015/03/01 v5547 L3 programming layer (code) 
  L3 Module: l3bootstrap 2015/02/28 v5542 L3 Bootstrap code
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\misc\etex.sty"
 Package: etex 2015/03/02 v2.1 eTeX basic definition package (PEB,DPC)
 \et@xins=\count88
 )
 L3 Module: l3names 2015/02/24 v5535 L3 Namespace for primitives
 L3 Module: l3basics 2015/01/27 v5500 L3 Basic definitions
 L3 Module: l3expan 2014/11/27 v5472 L3 Argument expansion
 L3 Module: l3tl 2015/01/27 v5500 L3 Token lists
 L3 Module: l3str 2015/03/01 v5545 L3 Strings
 L3 Module: l3seq 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Sequences and stacks
 L3 Module: l3int 2015/02/21 v5529 L3 Integers
  \c_max_int=\count89
 \l_tmpa_int=\count90
 \l_tmpb_int=\count91
 \g_tmpa_int=\count92
 \g_tmpb_int=\count93
L3 Module: l3quark 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Quarks
L3 Module: l3prg 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Control structures
 \g__prg_map_int=\count94
L3 Module: l3clist 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Comma separated lists
L3 Module: l3token 2014/09/15 v5422 L3 Experimental token manipulation
 L3 Module: l3prop 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Property lists
 L3 Module: l3msg 2015/02/26 v5537 L3 Messages
 L3 Module: l3file 2014/08/24 v5369 L3 File and I/O operations
 \l_iow_line_count_int=\count95
  \l__iow_target_count_int=\count96
 \l__iow_current_line_int=\count97
  \l__iow_current_word_int=\count98
 \l__iow_current_indentation_int=\count99
  L3 Module: l3skip 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Dimensions and skips
 \c_zero_dim=\dimen105
  \c_max_dim=\dimen106
 \l_tmpa_dim=\dimen107
  \l_tmpb_dim=\dimen108
  \g_tmpa_dim=\dimen109
  \g_tmpb_dim=\dimen110
 \c_zero_skip=\skip52
 \c_max_skip=\skip53
 \l_tmpa_skip=\skip54
 \l_tmpb_skip=\skip55
  \g_tmpa_skip=\skip56
 \g_tmpb_skip=\skip57
  \c_zero_muskip=\muskip10
 \c_max_muskip=\muskip11
 \l_tmpa_muskip=\muskip12
 \l_tmpb_muskip=\muskip13
  \g_tmpa_muskip=\muskip14
 \g_tmpb_muskip=\muskip15
 L3 Module: l3keys 2015/01/27 v5500 L3 Key-value interfaces
   \g__keyval_level_int=\count100
 \l_keys_choice_int=\count101
  L3 Module: l3fp 2014/08/22 v5336 L3 Floating points
       \c__fp_Bigg_trailing_shift_int=\count110
 L3 Module: l3box 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Experimental boxes
 \c_empty_box=\box26
 \l_tmpa_box=\box27
  \l_tmpb_box=\box28
 \g_tmpa_box=\box29
 \g_tmpb_box=\box30
  L3 Module: l3coffins 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Coffin code layer
 \l__coffin_internal_box=\box31
 \l__coffin_internal_dim=\dimen111
 \l__coffin_offset_x_dim=\dimen112
     \c_empty_coffin=\box32
  \l__coffin_aligned_coffin=\box33
 \l__coffin_aligned_internal_coffin=\box34
 \l_tmpa_coffin=\box35
  \l_tmpb_coffin=\box36
 \l__coffin_display_coffin=\box37
 \l__coffin_display_coord_coffin=\box38
 \l__coffin_display_pole_coffin=\box39
 \l__coffin_display_offset_dim=\dimen118
  \l__coffin_display_x_dim=\dimen119
 \l__coffin_display_y_dim=\dimen120
 L3 Module: l3color 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Experimental color support
 L3 Module: l3candidates 2015/03/01 v5544 L3 Experimental additions to l3kernel
 \l__box_top_dim=\dimen121
 \l__box_bottom_dim=\dimen122
 \l__box_left_dim=\dimen123
 \l__box_right_dim=\dimen124
  \l__box_top_new_dim=\dimen125
  \l__box_bottom_new_dim=\dimen126
 \l__box_left_new_dim=\dimen127
  \l__box_right_new_dim=\dimen128
 \l__box_internal_box=\box40
 \l__coffin_bounding_shift_dim=\dimen129
 \l__coffin_left_corner_dim=\dimen130
  \l__coffin_right_corner_dim=\dimen131
  \l__coffin_bottom_corner_dim=\dimen132
  \l__coffin_top_corner_dim=\dimen133
  \l__coffin_scaled_total_height_dim=\dimen134
  \l__coffin_scaled_width_dim=\dimen135
   )
  ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3unicode-data.def"
  File: l3unicode-data.def 2015/03/01 v5544 L3 Unicode data
  )
  ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3pdfmode.def"
  File: l3pdfmode.def 2015/03/01 v5544 L3 Experimental driver: PDF mode
  \l__driver_color_stack_int=\count111
 ))
  Package: xpatch 2012/10/02 v0.3 Extending etoolbox patching commands
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\l3packages\xparse\xparse.sty"
  Package: xparse 2014/11/25 v5471 L3 Experimental document command parser
  \l__xparse_current_arg_int=\count112
 \l__xparse_m_args_int=\count113
  \l__xparse_mandatory_args_int=\count114
  \l__xparse_processor_int=\count115
  \l__xparse_v_nesting_int=\count116
  )
  ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\etoolbox\etoolbox.sty"
  Package: etoolbox 2015/03/10 v2.1b e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
 \etb@tempcnta=\count117
     )
  LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
  Defining command \xpatchcmd with sig. '' on line 125.
   LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
  Defining command \xpretocmd with sig. '' on line 126.
   LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
 Defining command \xapptocmd with sig. '' on line 127.
 LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
 Defining command \xshowcmd with sig. '' on line 128.

 Defining command \xpretoindexfieldformat with sig. 'O{*}m' on line 165.
  LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
  LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
  Defining command \xshowbibdriver with sig. 'm' on line 193.
   ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\float\float.sty"
  Package: float 2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
 \c@float@type=\count118
  \float@exts=\toks14
 \float@box=\box41
 \@float@everytoks=\toks15
 \@floatcapt=\box42      ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\tools\afterpage.sty"
 Package: afterpage 2014/10/28 v1.08 After-Page Package (DPC)
\AP@output=\toks16
 \AP@partial=\box43
 \AP@footins=\box44
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\blindtext\blindtext.sty"
 Package: blindtext 2012/01/06 V2.0 blindtext-Package

 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\tools\xspace.sty"
 Package: xspace 2014/10/28 v1.13 Space after command names (DPC,MH)
 )
\c@blindtext=\count119
\c@Blindtext=\count120
 \c@blind@countparstart=\count121
 \blind@countxx=\count122
 \blindtext@numBlindtext=\count123
 \blind@countyy=\count124
 \c@blindlist=\count125
 \c@blindlistlevel=\count126
 \c@blindlist@level=\count127
 \blind@listitem=\count128
 \c@blind@listcount=\count129
 \c@blind@levelcount=\count130
 \blind@mathformula=\count131
 \blind@Mathformula=\count132
 \c@blind@randomcount=\count133
 \c@blind@randommax=\count134
 \c@blind@pangramcount=\count135
 \c@blind@pangrammax=\count136
 )
  Success
  ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\epigraph\epigraph.sty"
  Package: epigraph 2009/09/02 v1.5c typesetting epigraphs
  \beforeepigraphskip=\skip58
  \afterepigraphskip=\skip59
  \epigraphwidth=\skip60
  \epigraphrule=\skip61
  )
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\base\inputenc.sty"
 Package: inputenc 2014/04/30 v1.2b Input encoding file
  \inpenc@prehook=\toks17
   \inpenc@posthook=\toks18

  ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\base\utf8.def"
  File: utf8.def 2014/09/29 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  Now handling font encoding OML ...
  no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OML
  Now handling font encoding T1 ...
  processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding T1
  ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\base\t1enc.dfu"
  File: t1enc.dfu 2014/09/29 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A1 (decimal 161)
   defining Unicode char U+00A3 (decimal 163)
      defining Unicode char U+2423 (decimal 9251)
    Now handling font encoding OT1 ...
  ... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OT1

   ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\base\ot1enc.dfu"
   File: ot1enc.dfu 2014/09/29 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A1 (decimal 161)
    defining Unicode char U+00A3 (decimal 163)
    defining Unicode char U+00B8 (decimal 184)
     )
   Now handling font encoding OMS ...
   ... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OMS
      ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\base\omsenc.dfu"
   File: omsenc.dfu 2014/09/29 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
    defining Unicode char U+00A7 (decimal 167)
  defining Unicode char U+2022 (decimal 8226)
 Now handling font encoding OMX ...
 no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OMX
 Now handling font encoding U ...
 no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding U
   defining Unicode char U+00A9 (decimal 169)
     defining Unicode char U+2423 (decimal 9251)
  ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\babel\babel.sty"
   Package: babel 2014/09/25 3.9l The Babel package

  * Local config file bblopts.cfg used
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\00miktex\bblopts.cfg"
File: bblopts.cfg 2006/07/31 v1.0 MiKTeX 'babel' configuration
 )
   ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\babel-spanish\spanish.ldf"
   Language: spanish.ldf 2014/04/24 v5.0n Spanish support from the babel system

  ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\babel\babel.def"
  File: babel.def 2014/09/25 3.9l Babel common definitions
 \babel@savecnt=\count137
  \U@D=\dimen136
   \es@quottoks=\toks19
  \es@quotdepth=\count138
Package babel Info: Making " an active character on input line 516.
Package babel Info: Making < an active character on input line 662.
Package babel Info: Making > an active character on input line 662.
  ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
 Package: graphicx 2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

   ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty"
 Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
  \KV@toks@=\toks20
  )
  ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
  Package: graphics 2014/10/28 v1.0p Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

  ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty"
  Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
  )
   ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\00miktex\graphics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
 )
 Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 91.
  ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\pdftex-def\pdftex.def"
 File: pdftex.def 2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty"
 Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages         (HO)
  ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty"
 Package: ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
 \Gread@gobject=\count139
  \Gin@req@height=\dimen137
  \Gin@req@width=\dimen138
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\setspace\setspace.sty"
  Package: setspace 2011/12/19 v6.7a set line spacing
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\biblatex\biblatex.sty"
 Package: biblatex 2014/06/25 v2.9a programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)
  ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\biblatex\biblatex1.sty"
  Package: biblatex1 2014/06/25 v2.9a programmable bibliographies (bibtex)      (PK/JW
   /AB)
     ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\logreq\logreq.sty"
     Package: logreq 2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
     \lrq@indent=\count140
      ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\logreq\logreq.def"
      File: logreq.def 2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
      ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\base\ifthen.sty"
      Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
      ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\url\url.sty"
  \Urlmuskip=\muskip16
  Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  \c@tabx@nest=\count141
  \c@listtotal=\count142
  \c@parenlevel=\count167
  \blx@tempcnta=\count168
  \blx@tempcntb=\count169
 \blx@tempcntc=\count170
   \blx@maxsection=\count171
 \blx@maxsegment=\count172
 \blx@notetype=\count173
  \blx@parenlevel@text=\count174
 \blx@parenlevel@foot=\count175
 \labelnumberwidth=\skip62
 \labelalphawidth=\skip63
  \shorthandwidth=\skip64
\biblabelsep=\skip65
 \bibitemsep=\skip66
  \bibnamesep=\skip67
 \bibinitsep=\skip68
  \c@savedlabelname=\count180
  \c@author=\count181
  \c@savedauthor=\count182
  \c@shortauthor=\count183
 \c@savedshortauthor=\count184
\c@editor=\count185
 \c@savededitor=\count186
 \c@editora=\count187
\c@savededitora=\count188
 \c@editorb=\count189
\c@savededitorb=\count190
 \c@editorc=\count191
 \c@savededitorc=\count192
\c@shorteditor=\count193
 \c@savedshorteditor=\count194
 \c@bookauthor=\count195
 \c@savedbookauthor=\count196
\c@translator=\count197
\c@savedtranslator=\count198
\c@annotator=\count199
 \c@savedannotator=\count200
  \c@commentator=\count201
  Normal \count register pool exhausted, switching to extended pool.

   \c@savedlistf=\count319
   Package biblatex Info: Trying to load compatibility code...
   Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-compat.def' found.
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\biblatex\blx-compat.def"
  File: blx-compat.def 2014/06/25 v2.9a biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)

  Package biblatex Info: Trying to load generic definitions...
  Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex.def' found.

  ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\biblatex\biblatex.def"
 File: biblatex.def 
  \c@textcitecount=\count320
  \c@textcitetotal=\count321
  \c@textcitemaxnames=\count322
 \c@biburlnumpenalty=\count323
 \c@biburlucpenalty=\count324
 \c@biburllcpenalty=\count325
  \c@smartand=\count326
  Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'chem-angew'...
  Package biblatex Info: ... file 'chem-angew.bbx' found.

  ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\biblatex-chem\chem-angew.bbx"
  File: chem-angew.bbx 2014/11/14 v1.1m biblatex bibliography style
 Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'numeric-comp'...
 Package biblatex Info: ... file 'numeric-comp.bbx' found.

 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\biblatex\bbx\numeric-comp.bbx"
  File: numeric-comp.bbx 2014/06/25 v2.9a biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
  Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'numeric'...
 Package biblatex Info: ... file 'numeric.bbx' found.
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\biblatex\bbx\numeric.bbx"
  File: numeric.bbx 2014/06/25 v2.9a biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
 Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'standard'...
 Package biblatex Info: ... file 'standard.bbx' found.
  ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\biblatex\bbx\standard.bbx"
  File: standard.bbx 2014/06/25 v2.9a biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
 \c@bbx:relatedcount=\count327
  \c@bbx:relatedtotal=\count328
  Package biblatex Info: Trying to load citation style 'numeric-comp'...
   Package biblatex Info: ... file 'numeric-comp.cbx' found.
   ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\biblatex\cbx\numeric-comp.cbx"
  File: numeric-comp.cbx 2014/06/25 v2.9a biblatex citation style (PK/JW/AB)
 \c@cbx@tempcnta=\count329
 \c@cbx@tempcntb=\count330

Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\cites'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\parencites'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\smartcites'.
 Package biblatex Info: Trying to load configuration file...
 Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex.cfg' found.
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\biblatex\biblatex.cfg"
File: biblatex.cfg 
  ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\csquotes\csquotes.sty"
  Package: csquotes 2011/10/22 v5.1d context-sensitive quotations
 \csq@ltx@everypar=\toks21
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\csquotes\csquotes.def"
 File: csquotes.def 2011/10/22 v5.1d csquotes generic definitions
 Package csquotes Info: Trying to load configuration file 'csquotes.cfg'...
Package csquotes Info: ... configuration file loaded successfully.
  ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\csquotes\csquotes.cfg"
  File: csquotes.cfg 
  ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\titlesec\titlesec.sty"
  Package: titlesec 2011/12/15 v2.10.0 Sectioning titles
 \ttl@box=\box45
 \beforetitleunit=\skip71
 \aftertitleunit=\skip72
\ttl@plus=\dimen139
\ttl@minus=\dimen140
  \ttl@toksa=\toks22
  \titlewidth=\dimen141
   \titlewidthlast=\dimen142
 \titlewidthfirst=\dimen143
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\tocloft\tocloft.sty"
 Package: tocloft 2013/05/02 v2.3f parameterised ToC, etc., typesetting
  Package tocloft Info: The document has chapter divisions on input line 44.
\cftparskip=\skip73
 \cftbeforetoctitleskip=\skip74
 \cftaftertoctitleskip=\skip75
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\tabu\tabu.sty"
 Package: tabu 2011/02/26 v2.8 - flexible LaTeX tabulars (FC)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\tools\array.sty"
 Package: array 2014/10/28 v2.4c Tabular extension package (FMi)
\col@sep=\dimen144
 \extrarowheight=\dimen145
 \NC@list=\toks23
 \extratabsurround=\skip107
\backup@length=\skip108
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\ltxmisc\varwidth.sty"
 Package: varwidth 2009/03/30 ver 0.92;  Variable-width minipages
  \@vwid@box=\box46
  \sift@deathcycles=\count339
  \@vwid@loff=\dimen146
  \@vwid@roff=\dimen147
  \c@taburow=\count340
 \tabu@nbcols=\count341
 \tabu@cnt=\count342
\tabu@Xcol=\count343
  \tabu@target=\dimen148
\abovetabulinesep=\dimen154\belowtabulinesep=\dimen155
 \tabustrutrule=\dimen156
\tabu@thebody=\toks24
 \tabu@cellskip=\skip109
  \@indexfile=\write4
  Writing index file bravenewworld.idx
  ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\acronym\acronym.sty"
 Package: acronym 2014/09/29 v1.40 Support for acronyms (Tobias Oetiker)

  ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\bigfoot\suffix.sty"
 Package: suffix 2006/07/15 1.5a Variant command support
     ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\xstring\xstring.sty"
  ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\generic\xstring\xstring.tex"
 \@xs@message=\write5
 \integerpart=\count346
 \decimalpart=\count347
  Package: xstring 2013/10/13  v1.7c  String manipulations (C Tellechea)
 \AC@clearlist=\toks26
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\caption\caption.sty"
Package: caption 2013/05/02 v3.3-89 Customizing captions (AR)
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\caption\caption3.sty"
 Package: caption3 2013/05/02 v1.6-88 caption3 kernel (AR)
 Package caption3 Info: TeX engine: e-TeX on input line 57.
 \captionmargin=\dimen157
 \c@ContinuedFloat=\count348
  Package caption Info: float package is loaded.
  Package biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'spanish'...
 Package biblatex Info: ... file 'spanish.lbx' found.
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\latex\biblatex\lbx\spanish.lbx"
File: spanish.lbx 2014/06/25 v2.9a biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
  Package csquotes Info: Checking for multilingual support...
 Package csquotes Info: ... found 'babel' package.
 Package csquotes Info: Adjusting default style.
 Package csquotes Info: Redefining alias 'default' -> 'spanish'.

(bravenewworld.aux)
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 57.
 LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 57.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 57.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 57.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 57.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 57.
 LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 57.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 57.
 LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 57.
 LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 57.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 57.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 57.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \sptext on input line 57.
```

LaTeX Info: Redefining . on input line 57.
    LaTeX Info: Redefining \% on input line 57.

```
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 (2)\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii"
 [Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count349
\scratchdimen=\dimen164
\scratchbox=\box51
\nofMPsegments=\count350
\nofMParguments=\count351
\everyMPshowfont=\toks27
\MPscratchCnt=\count352
\MPscratchDim=\dimen165
\MPnumerator=\count353
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count354
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks28   
Package biblatex Info: Input encoding 'utf8' detected.
  Package biblatex Info: Data encoding 'ascii' specified.
 (biblatex)             No need to reencode data.
 Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliographic data...
 Package biblatex Info: ... file 'bravenewworld.bbl' found.
   (bravenewworld.bbl)
Package biblatex Info: Reference section=0 on input line 57.
 Package biblatex Info: Reference segment=0 on input line 57.
Package caption Info: Begin \AtBeginDocument code.
 Package caption Info: End \AtBeginDocument code.
  (capitulos/titulo.tex
 ! I can't write on file `bravenewworld.pdf'.
 Please type another file name for output
 ! Emergency stop.
  <argument> ...stobj \GPT@objref }}}\fi \pdfximage 
                                              \GPT@RuleAttr \ifx \GPT@pa...
 l.12           \includegraphics[width=4cm]{logo}

 *** (job aborted, file error in nonstop mode)

  Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
  16918 strings out of 493698
  296036 string characters out of 3142800
  430248 words of memory out of 3000000
  20094 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
  3945 words of font info for 15 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1025 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
  39i,1n,43p,10407b,662s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
 !  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: Are you sure that your `tesis.pdf` document is not already open before compilation in a pdf-reader which does allows for modification? That is what the error message suggests to me.

Comment: @DRi I have already checked that and it was not open

Comment: Is the `logo` file in the same folder as `titulo2.tex`, not the one of the main file `tesis.tex`?

Comment: @DRi I have all the figures, including `logo` in the same folder, `figuras`. I have included in the preamble `\graphicspath{{./figuras/}}`

Comment: Sorry,my previous command was wrong, you should have either: `logo` in the same folder as the main file and use `\includegraphics[width=4cm]{logo}` or `logo`in an other folder and use `\includegraphics[width=4cm]{figuras/logo}

Comment: Sorry again, I didn't notice the graphicpath,  with this and the logo file in the `figuras` folder it works fine for me

Comment: It's ok. but I still have the same error message, I really don't know why because yesterday it worked perfectly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37468/discussion-between-dri-and-leila).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out which the mistake was. There was an extra '}' somewhere in the text I wrote. It took so long to find it out. I am novice, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

On my machine (Ubuntu12.04, TeXLive) your code works fine.
But since you are on a Windows machine your graphicpath should probably be written differently, something like:

```
\graphicspath{{D:/Leila@Tesis/figuras/}}
```

Maybe you already had a look at this question [how-to-use-graphicspath](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139401/how-to-use-graphicspath)