# How to use \includegraphics?

Tags: graphics, packages

I am sorry if my question is too silly, I am totally new to LaTeX.

I have just downloaded TeXstudio 2 days ago and am trying to include some figures/images in the document. I found out about the `\includegraphics` command but cannot understand how it works at all. Every guide I have found jump to something like

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{bird1}
```

and I don't have a clue how I am supposed to use the command except that I need to use the package `graphicx`.

Where do I have to put my images so that TeXstudio can find it? Let's say I have an image called `cat.png` located at `C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\PICS`, do I just type `\includegraphics{cat}` and TeXstudio is going to magically find it?

Comment: If it is in the same folder as the `.tex` file, it will find magically find it. The package also has the command `\graphicspath` so you could put the images in a subdirectory (e.g., `\graphicspath{{jpg/}{png/}}`) -- though how this works exactly on Windows is not clear to me.  Luckily there are experts around....

Comment: Can anybody post the authoritative link to the `\includegraphics` command documentation?

Comment: Using amsart the command \includegraphics is not recognized.

Comment: This video contains your answer. [How to add a figure in LaTeX using \includegraphics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3BBWku9fayQ&t=2s)

Comment: @WilliamEntriken (and future readers coming across this, if any) `texdoc graphicx`, or unofficial LaTeX reference manual, page 212. special case of [macros - Where do I find out how a command/environment is defined? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4327/250119) I guess

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The easiest way is to put the pictures in the same directory as your (main) LaTeX document. Then

```
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{bird1}
```

is working fine. If you put it in some subfolder (relative to the main document) you say, e.g.

```
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Pics/bird1}
```

Or you can define where LaTeX should look for pictures using the `\graphicspath` command in the preamble, e.g. when you sort your pictures to corresponding folders

```
\graphicspath{
    {Pics/PDFs/}
    {Pics/JPGs/}
    {Pics/PNGs/}
}
```

and LaTeX will search the folders in the given order using the first found picture matching the name given to `\includegraphics`.

Comment: Thank you a lot! It seems to be working after I move the image to the same folder containing the document. Just 1 more question, I still don't quite understand the structure of \graphicspath command. Could you please explain it in a bit more detailed?

Comment: Have a look at [that question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139401/how-to-use-graphicspath) and the corresponding answers. Is that enough?

Comment: You really helped me a lot, thank you again. I wish I could upvote more than 1 time.

Comment: what do the ``/`` correspond to in ``\graphicspath``? I currently have one like this ``\graphicspath{{images/}}`` and it only seems to work with one of the ``/``. I don't know why there needs to be a nested argument either.

Comment: The forward slash is for directories. So "images/" is a directory. But you can also leave it out. It's only required for nested directories like "images/favourite/" or "images/favourite". The nested arguments are because you can use space and commas inside a file name but not curly brackets. So it can decide if its still part of the file name or not. Hope that helped