# picture not included - code that has been working throws error

Tags: includegraphics, miktex2.9

This has been working before, see e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/301494/137734) for reference.
The png picture is in the same folder as the latex document. Do I miss anything?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

Start with nice text...

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Temperatur.png}
  %\caption{}
    %\caption{Schema des Verkehrsflusses \protect\\\hspace{\textwidth} aus http://www.mathe.tu-freiberg.de/~bernstei/HMI/Verkehr.html.
  %\label{}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The first part of the error:

[image]

Comment: Your code works fine for me, may be this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511138/miktex-graphics-version-1-3b-bug-on-windows-10-setcurrfile-undefined will helps you...

Comment: Update your miktex both in user mode and admin mode.

Comment: @MadyYuvi The link solved my problem!! Thanks a lot - you saved my life ;-)

Comment: @daleif the update was the problem - see above ;-)

Comment: @Christoph Glad to hear that you solved the issue....