# No figure on L4DC/PMLR template

Tags: graphics

I'm considering taking part in a conference named L4DC [whose template is PMLR format](https://l4dc.seas.upenn.edu/contribute/)

However, no figure appears on the PDF. The error saying  or <File sample" not found >

Unfortunately, any possible solution I found on the internet didn't work, such as adding `\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}` to preamble.

Could you give me some tips to solve this?
Thank you.

MY PREAMBLE and CODE

```
\documentclass[12pt, draft]{l4dc2023}

% The following packages will be automatically loaded:
% amsmath, amssymb, natbib, graphicx, url, algorithm2e
\usepackage{times}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering

\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{sample}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

AND this is "sample" image[image]

AND here is .log file

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.5.13)  10 NOV 2022 08:39
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**l4dc2023-sample
(./l4dc2023-sample.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-05-07> (./l4dc2023.cls
Document Class: l4dc2023 2023/04/01 v2.0 L4DC 2023 Proceedings
(./jmlr.cls
Document Class: jmlr 2017/08/01 v1.24 (NLCT) Journal of Machine Learning Resear
ch
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2020/11/20 v2.8 package option processing (HA)

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks15
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks16

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))
\XKV@depth=\count179
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty
Package: calc 2017/05/25 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
\calc@Acount=\count180
\calc@Bcount=\count181
\calc@Adimen=\dimen138
\calc@Bdimen=\dimen139
\calc@Askip=\skip47
\calc@Bskip=\skip48
LaTeX Info: Redefining \setlength on input line 80.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \addtolength on input line 81.
\calc@Ccount=\count182
\calc@Cskip=\skip49
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count183
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo
File: size11.clo 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count184
\c@section=\count185
\c@subsection=\count186
\c@subsubsection=\count187
\c@paragraph=\count188
\c@subparagraph=\count189
\c@figure=\count190
\c@table=\count191
\abovecaptionskip=\skip50
\belowcaptionskip=\skip51
\bibindent=\dimen140
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2020/09/23 v2.17i AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip52

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks17
\ex@=\dimen141
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen142
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count192
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 234.
\uproot@=\count193
\leftroot@=\count194
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 399.
\classnum@=\count195
\DOTSCASE@=\count196
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 496.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 499.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 620.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box47
\strutbox@=\box48
\big@size=\dimen143
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 743.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 744.
\macc@depth=\count197
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count198
\dotsspace@=\muskip16
\c@parentequation=\count199
\dspbrk@lvl=\count266
\tag@help=\toks18
\row@=\count267
\column@=\count268
\maxfields@=\count269
\andhelp@=\toks19
\eqnshift@=\dimen144
\alignsep@=\dimen145
\tagshift@=\dimen146
\tagwidth@=\dimen147
\totwidth@=\dimen148
\lineht@=\dimen149
\@envbody=\toks20
\multlinegap=\skip53
\multlinetaggap=\skip54
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks21
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2923.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2924.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \hbar on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty
Package: natbib 2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)
\bibhang=\skip55
\bibsep=\skip56
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cite on input line 694.
\c@NAT@ctr=\count270
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2020/09/09 v1.2b Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2020/08/30 v1.4c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 105.

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2020/10/05 v1.2a Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen150
\Gin@req@width=\dimen151
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip17
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1352.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/x11nam.def
File: x11nam.def 2016/05/11 v2.12 Predefined colors according to Unix/X11 (UK)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/algorithm2e/algorithm2e.sty
Package: algorithm2e 2017/07/18 v5.2 algorithms environments
\c@AlgoLine=\count271

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
\algocf@hangindent=\skip57

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifoddpage/ifoddpage.sty
Package: ifoddpage 2016/04/23 v1.1 Conditionals for odd/even page detection
\c@checkoddpage=\count272
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/xspace.sty
Package: xspace 2014/10/28 v1.13 Space after command names (DPC,MH)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/relsize/relsize.sty
Package: relsize 2013/03/29 ver 4.1
)
\skiptotal=\skip58
\skiplinenumber=\skip59
\skiprule=\skip60
\skiphlne=\skip61
\skiptext=\skip62
\skiplength=\skip63
\algomargin=\skip64
\skipalgocfslide=\skip65
\algowidth=\dimen152
\inoutsize=\dimen153
\inoutindent=\dimen154
\interspacetitleruled=\dimen155
\interspacealgoruled=\dimen156
\interspacetitleboxruled=\dimen157
\algocf@ruledwidth=\skip66
\algocf@inoutbox=\box49
\algocf@inputbox=\box50
\AlCapSkip=\skip67
\AlCapHSkip=\skip68
\algoskipindent=\skip69
\algocf@nlbox=\box51
\algocf@hangingbox=\box52
\algocf@untilbox=\box53
\algocf@skipuntil=\skip70
\algocf@capbox=\box54
\algocf@lcaptionbox=\skip71
\algoheightruledefault=\skip72
\algoheightrule=\skip73
\algotitleheightruledefault=\skip74
\algotitleheightrule=\skip75
\c@algocfline=\count273
\c@algocfproc=\count274
\c@algocf=\count275
\algocf@algoframe=\box55
\algocf@algobox=\box56
)
(./jmlrutils.sty
Package: jmlrutils 2017/08/01
\c@subfigure=\count276
\@subfloatcapbox=\box57
\@subfloatcontsbox=\box58
\c@subtable=\count277
\c@example=\count278
\c@theorem=\count279
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
Package: hyperref 2021-02-27 v7.00k Hypertext links for LaTeX

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty
Package: pdfescape 2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty
Package: hycolor 2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty
Package: letltxmacro 2019/12/03 v1.6 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty
Package: auxhook 2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2020-10-07 v3.14 Key value format for package options (HO)
)
\@linkdim=\dimen158
\Hy@linkcounter=\count280
\Hy@pagecounter=\count281

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def
File: pd1enc.def 2021-02-27 v7.00k Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PD1 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PD1
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref-langpatches.def
File: hyperref-langpatches.def 2021-02-27 v7.00k Hyperref: patches for babel la
nguages
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty
Package: intcalc 2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count282

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def
File: puenc.def 2021-02-27 v7.00k Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PU ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PU
)
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4192.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4197.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4200.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4207.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4212.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4445.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count283
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 4804.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen159

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
Package: bitset 2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty
Package: bigintcalc 2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO
)
))
\Fld@menulength=\count284
\Field@Width=\dimen160
\Fld@charsize=\dimen161
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6075.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6080.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6083.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6090.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6095.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6100.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6105.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 6145.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 6149.

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty
Package: atbegshi-ltx 2020/08/17 v1.0a Emulation of the original atbegshi packa
ge
with kernel methods
)
\Hy@abspage=\count285
\c@Item=\count286
\c@Hfootnote=\count287
)
Package hyperref Info: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
File: hpdftex.def 2021-02-27 v7.00k Hyperref driver for pdfTeX

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty
Package: atveryend-ltx 2020/08/19 v1.0a Emulation of the original atvery packag
e
with kernel methods
)
\Fld@listcount=\count288
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count289

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
Package: rerunfilecheck 2019/12/05 v1.9 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty
Package: uniquecounter 2019/12/15 v1.4 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 2
86.
)
\Hy@SectionHShift=\skip76
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
Package: nameref 2021-04-02 v2.47 Cross-referencing by name of section

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty
Package: refcount 2019/12/15 v3.6 Data extraction from label references (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.s
ty
Package: gettitlestring 2019/12/15 v1.6 Cleanup title references (HO)
)
\c@section@level=\count290
)
Package hyperref Info: Option `colorlinks' set `true' on input line 164.
Package hyperref Info: Option `linktocpage' set `true' on input line 164.
Package hyperref Info: Option `plainpages' set `false' on input line 164.
\aftertitskip=\skip77
\beforetitskip=\skip78
\interauthorskip=\skip79
\aftermaketitskip=\skip80
\jmlrlength=\skip81
\jmlrbox=\box59
\c@chapter=\count291
\postchapterskip=\skip82
\prechapterskip=\skip83
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/times.sty
Package: times 2020/03/25 PSNFSS-v9.3 (SPQR) 
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for OT1+ptm on input line 5
.

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1ptm.fd
File: ot1ptm.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/ptm.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2021-05-07 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count292
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box60
)

LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [12pt].

(./l4dc2023-sample.aux)
\openout1 = `l4dc2023-sample.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PD1/pdf/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PU/pdf/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count293
\scratchdimen=\dimen162
\scratchbox=\box61
\nofMPsegments=\count294
\nofMParguments=\count295
\everyMPshowfont=\toks22
\MPscratchCnt=\count296
\MPscratchDim=\dimen163
\MPnumerator=\count297
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count298
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks23
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
85.

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Liv
e
))
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring ON on input line 5.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 5.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 5.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nameref on input line 5.

(./l4dc2023-sample.out) (./l4dc2023-sample.out)
\@outlinefile=\write3
\openout3 = `l4dc2023-sample.out'.

<sample.png, id=4, 425.59pt x 283.0575pt>
File: sample.png Graphic file (type png)
<use sample.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: sample.png  used on input line 8.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 180.67499pt x 120.1661pt.
 [1{/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}

 <./sample.png>]
(./l4dc2023-sample.aux)
Package rerunfilecheck Info: File `l4dc2023-sample.out' has not changed.
(rerunfilecheck)             Checksum: D41D8CD98F00B204E9800998ECF8427E;0.
 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 12117 strings out of 478846
 175368 string characters out of 5855768
 506545 words of memory out of 5000000
 29594 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 407546 words of font info for 33 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 89i,6n,91p,337b,330s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
{/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/8r.enc}</usr/local/t
exlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/urw/times/utmr8a.pfb>
Output written on l4dc2023-sample.pdf (1 page, 40288 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 22 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 15 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 3 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 6 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: The reason could be the draft option in the options of the document class. Delete it and the graphics should be shown.

Comment: Thank you! But didn't work...:(   I did ```\documentclass[12pt]{l4dc2023}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example with the deactivated draft mode and an example-image works for me with an actual miktex distribution.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{l4dc2023} % draft deleted
% The following packages will be automatically loaded:
% amsmath, amssymb, natbib, graphicx, url, algorithm2e
\usepackage{times}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image} % another graphic
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Wow, idk what is the difference ... I'm using Atom editor

Comment: The error saying ```latexmk: Failure in some part of making files  &
File ‘sample’ not found```

Comment: But I'm sure the png and .tex  are in the same place

Comment: Can you compile from the command line? For example with: `pdflatex filename`

Comment: Please show us the `log file`.

Comment: Surprisingly, using  pdflatex filename, the image is shown. Thank you! But you know, it's a bit demanding. I want to compile and save at the same time. (like, "command+ S")

Comment: I don´t use the atom editor. You should check the settings of the installed packages for latex in the atom editor. You can also test the editor texworks, which should be installed with your latex distribution.

Answer (score 2):

The line `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{sample}` is supposed to insert a graphic from a separate file. In this case, the filename is `sample` (with an extension and file type that `\includegraphics` can read and use; see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1072/which-graphics-formats-can-be-included-in-documents-processed-by-latex-or-pdflat)).

The error you appear to be getting is because you don't have a file named 'sample' where pdflatex can find it. To fix this, change `sample` in that line to the name of an image file you do have in the same folder as you .tex file.

There is some other advice (including using pictures in another directory) and basic use of `\includegraphics` [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301494/how-to-use-includegraphics), which might also help.

Comment: Thank you! Tho, I have a png image named "sample"  in the same folder containing .tex file

Comment: @SpaceTAKA, since you have a file which should work, and doesn't, you might want to add the log file contents here, so someone can see if there is another problem which is causing the symptoms you see. Please edit it into the question, don't leave it as a comment on either the question or answer.

Comment: Thank you! I just added the sample image :)