# Including images by file path in lyx

Tags: graphics, lyx

I am trying to include an image by path into a **lyx** document. My latex code is the following:

```
\begin{figure}
\graphicspath{{C:\Paper\images\}}
\centering\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{imageName}\caption{This is an image}
\end{figure}
```

but I get the error:

```
Paragraph ended before \graphicspath was complete
```

How can I set the path? Is it possible to set it once in the preamble?

Comment: Try replacing backslashes with slashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is the `\`. You should use `/` in the path like discussed in the following answer:

[How to use \graphicspath?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139401/how-to-use-graphicspath#139403)

There is also a more general path description provided.

Your path should look like:

```
\graphicspath{{C:/Paper/images/}}
```