# standalone - build option not working with \graphicspath

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone

I have a TikZ figure (*fig.tex*) in a subfolder as an standalone, and I want to use `mode=buildnew` in my main document so that I can optimize compilation times. I indicate the subfolder by using `\graphicspath{{images/}}`.

However, the figure is not build separately but compiled every time, together with the main document, and I get the warning `Graphic 'fig.pdf' could not be build`.

If I move *fig.tex* out of the subfolder, and leave it in the main one, together with *main.tex*, then it works properly and generates *fig.pdf*. I would like to get this result also when referring to TikZ figures in the subfolder.

I have version 1.2 of the `standalone` package and I included the "magic" TeXstudio comment `% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///pdflatex/[-shell-escape]` in the main file, according to some of the answers that I have found around.

Here is the MWE:

*fig.tex*

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=35mm,auto]

\node[draw,fill=yellow] (n) {Fig};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

*main.tex*

```
% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///pdflatex/[-shell-escape]
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[mode=buildnew]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\selectlanguage{british}

\graphicspath{{images/}}

\begin{document}

Text.

\includestandalone{fig}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT:**

Some things I already tried:

- Adding `--enable-write18` to the magic comment.
- Changing the path to `\graphicspath{{./images/}}`.

And some additional information

- If I use `\includestandalone{images/fig}` and take away `\graphicspath` it works properly and the figure is compiled.
- My OS is Windows 10.

Comment: It works for me. But you could try relativ path `\graphicspath{{./images/}}` (see [question here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139401/how-to-use-graphicspath))

Comment: I tried it, but did not work. I will add it to the question.

Comment: it works for me also. Although when compiling main file message `Package standalone Warning: Graphic 'fig.pdf' could not be build.` is shown, the final result includes the standalone figure as expected.

Comment: Maybe I should make the question more explicit. It compiles correctly for me too in all cases, but the point is that I want to compile the TikZ figures just when they are new and just once, for optimisation reasons, since I have documents with a lot of them. Hence the `buildnew` option. So it should generate the _fig.aux_, _fig.log_ and _fig.pdf_ in all cases, and give no warnings, but it does not work. Should I edit the question to make it less confusing?

Comment: The use of `\graphicspath` is not yet a feature of `standalone`. However, there is already a [feature request](https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/standalone/issues/6/make-use-of-graphicspath) for it.