# How can i include pictures?

Tags: graphics

What should i do ,i'm trying to add some picture but i have this error.[image]

Comment: And what can i do ?

Comment: You have to use ordinary slashes instead of the backslashes. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139401/how-to-use-graphicspath

Comment: @Jürgen Not the forward slash, but the backslashes, as gernot mentions. Note from that error that it interprets `\Users` as a macro/control sequence, which it of course isn't.