# graphicspath returning error

Tags: graphics

I am tryig to use graphicspath to specify a directory where i keep all of my images. Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{C:/Users/Me/OneDrive - UofO/LaTeX/IEEEtran/Images/}}


\begin{document}


A schematic is illustrated in figure \ref{Schematic}c.
\FloatBarrier
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Schematic.png}
\caption{Schematic}
\label{Schematic}
\end{figure}
\FloatBarrier
\end{document}
```

However I get an error, '! Package pdftex.def Error: File `Schematic.png' not found.'

I have seen several other threads on this topic, I have tried removing the / after Images in graphicspath, I have quadruple checked that the directory is correct, I have made sure that I am compiling with pdfLaTex. But still nothing seems to work here. Any suggestions on what's going wrong?

Comment: Please, take a look at this question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139401/how-to-use-graphicspath

Comment: It's possible that the space in the path may cause a problem. Try with [`grffile`](https://ctan.org/pkg/grffile).

Comment: The true fix is remove spaces in directory names, which are only good to cause unexpected problems and maintain you aware of them.