# Cannot load a graphic to my Tex file

Tags: graphics

The figure (p201.png) is on my desktop and I did simply as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{/Users/prinelo/Desktop}
\begin{document}
    content...
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{p201.png}
\end{document}
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: You need a backslash after `Desktop/`.

Comment: @JānisLazovskis No backslash! You show a slash. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139401/how-to-use-graphicspath

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek According to your instruction, it works in this sample, but when the same condition applied to my book, it does not manifest the figure but instead of a figure in which it shows exactly the name of the whole path, i.e., "/Users/prinelo/Desktop/p201.png".

Comment: @TeXnician it requires a slash (not backslash of course) after the final directory and double curly braces.  However, now it works for this sample file, but when the same condition applied to my book, it does not manifest the figure but instead of a figure in which it shows exactly the name of the whole path, i.e., "/Users/prinelo/Desktop/p201.png".

Comment: @KingChungLo Likely, the book uses option `draft` as global option (`\documentclass`) or package option.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Oh, i c. After deleting draft, it works now. Thanks!