# How to \input or \include files from different directories?

Tags: input, include, directory, structure

**My folder structure looks like that:**

[image]

---

While putting the chapters into the base file `Report.tex` works completely fine I get trouble when I try to insert the graphics into the chapters.

For example: How can I put the file `Image_1` into `Chapter_1.tex`? As you can see the target file `Image_1` is located in a neighboured directory of `Chapter_1.tex`.

Some command in `Chapter_1.tex` like...

```
\includegraphics[blabla]{../Graphics/Image_1}
```

... leads to the error "! LaTeX Error: File `../Graphics/Image_1' not found."

---

**Minimum Working Examples (MWE):**

For file `Report.tex` in root directory:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

    \input{Chapters/Chapter_1}

    \input{Chapters/Chapter_2}

    \input{Chapters/Chapter_3}

\end{document}
```

For file `Chapter_1.tex` in subdirectory `Chapters`:

```
\chapter{First chapter}

\blindtext

\includegraphics{../Graphics/Image_1}
```

For file `Image_1.tex` in subdirectory `Graphics`:

```
\includegraphics{example-image-golden}
```

---

Do you have any ideas how to cross-input files from parallel directories? Thank you very much!

Comment: Well, without an MWE it's hard to give you an accurate answer. I understand that [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139401/how-to-use-graphicspath) could solve the problem of your graphics. For the chapters, you need to add the path into the `\include{}` command.

Comment: @Aradnix: Thank you very much for your kind reply! I added the belonging MWE. I would love to add the image without further packages if it is possible?

Comment: checking with \graphicspath{{../figure_folder/,../figure_subfolder/,}}, so that it will check all the folder paths

Comment: I think within the file that's `\input` you need to use the path relative to the root file (not the input file), so try `\includegraphics{Graphics/Image_1}` instead.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot: You are right, thank you very much! Indeed the path will be taken from the root file what means that subdirectories can be accessed. You can post this as an answer if you want. :-)

Comment: @Dave Okay. Done :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Files that are `\input` need to use a path relative to the root file (the one containing `\documentclass`) not to the included file, so you need to use

```
\includegraphics{Graphics/Image_1}
```

instead of

```
\includegraphics{../Graphics/Image_1}
```

It's probably simpler to use `\graphicspath` in the root file so you don't have to worry about the paths:

```
\graphicspath{{Graphics/}}
```

or if you have sub-directories within `Graphics`:

```
\graphicspath{{Graphics/}{Graphics/subDir1/}{Graphics/subDir2/}}
```

then you just need to use

```
\includegraphics{Image_1}
```