# Folders in a latex project/thesis

Tags: graphics, external-files

How do you make folders in a latex project ? I created a folder inside my main folder but my structure window doesn't show it. I am using OSX and Texmaker latest version?

This is the folder that I created (figure 1), and I am trying to add UniversityLogo.png on my main text file but I get this error (figure 2).

The code that I am using is

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\graphicspath{{Images/}} 

\title{
        {Thesis Title}\\
        {\large Old Dominion University}\\
        {\includegraphics{UniversityLogo.png}}
}
\author{My Name}
\date{Day Month Year}

\begin{document}

\maketitle 

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome. Do you mean Texmaker? I think it only shows files that are included in your main file with `\include` or `\input`.

Comment: Yes I mean textmaker. I created a folder inside my main folder called Images. I tried to call this folder from the preamble graphicspath{{Images/}} then i use \insertgraphics{logo.png} and there is a message that saying that the file is not being found. :/

Comment: Texmaker != Textmaker. What you describe should work I think, and indeed it does work here (Linux). Can you edit your question with more detail about your file and folder structure, and perhaps also include a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228) to make it clear what you did in the code.

Comment: Hard to say, that setup works fine here. The only thing that catches my eye is that there seems to be a space at the end of the name of the `Thesis` folder, i.e. `Thesis<space>`. Spaces in paths have a tendency to not work well, though I cannot say if it would be a problem in this case.

Comment: Fixed the spaced and still didnt work :/ its good no worries! I will figured it out! thanks though

Answer (score 1):

I do not have enough reputation to comment so I write it into an answer.
Maybe it works if you use `\graphicspath{{./Images/}}` as in this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139401/how-to-use-graphicspath).

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: Hi EuklidAlexandria I tried this too and it didnt work :(

Comment: Hm, does it work with `\includegraphics{Images/UniversityLogo}`?

Comment: @MartinLiza See above comment. (EuklidAlexandria: Hi, welcome. Note that other users are in general not notified of comments, so use an at-sign followed by the username to ping them, as I did with Martin here. Only other commenters can be pinged though, and maximum one user per comment. You as the owner of the post are always notified of comments.)

Comment: @EuklidAlexandria, I tried that too and it didnt work :(

Comment: @MartinLiza Could it be that the I in Images is a small L?