# Figure generated with gnuplot-cairolatex is not properly shown when the figures are in a different directory

Tags: floats, gnuplot

I use `gnuplot` with the term `cairolatex` to create and incorporate graphics to my LaTeX projects. This terminal returns two files. One is `*.tex` and the other one is `*.svg`.

But I'm having trouble when I try to organize the project into different directories. For instance, I've created a folder `\fig` for all the figures. To include them, I use the piece of code below.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \scalebox{0.55}{\input{project/fig/fig1.tex}}
  \caption{some caption}
  \label{fig:some label}
\end{figure}
```

But when I do so, even though, when both files are in the directory `project/fig/` it seems like just the file `*.tex` is imported.

I've got something like this:

[image: What I get]

But I'm expecting this:

[image: What I expect]

It's a bit annoying because sometimes I have to manage several figures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look inside the file `fig1.tex`, you will find a line like this

```
\put(0,0){\includegraphics{fig1}}%
```

This means that TeX expects the file `fig.svg` or `fig1.pdf` in the current directory, i.e. the directory where your main tex file resides.  However, the file is in `project/fig/` directory, so TeX cannot find it.

Try adding the subdirectory to `graphicspath`:

```
\graphicspath{{project/fig1/}{another subdirectory}{yet another directory}...}
```

Another option is directly editing tex files produces by gnuplot to give the explicit location of included graphics files.

Comment: It didn't work :c I added the line \graphicspath{{project/fig}} in the header of the main.tex file.

Comment: You should use `project/fig/` with the trailing slash, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139401/how-to-use-graphicspath