# Trouble with input command using pdf_tex files generated by Inkscape

Tags: pdftex, input, compilation-error

I have a problem when I use `\input{}` command with `pdf_tex` files generated by Inkscape in subfolders. It appears an error that says

> ​! Package pdftex.def Error: File `X.pdf' not found: using draft setting.

However, when I use `\input{}` command with `pdf_tex` in files in the same folder, then main document trouble doesn't appear. The above description originally happened in a report with a Masterfile and in chapter I wrote the input command (using `\graphicspath{images/}`)

I attach a MWE with the same error and the same preamble that the Masterfile and part of the log file with the error. BTW I am using MiKTeX and Windows 10 (versions installed this 2020).

Code:

```latex
%==================================PAQUETES INICIALES==================================%

%------------------------Clase de documento y configuraciones--------------------------%
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%


%-----------------------------Paquetes generales texto---------------------------------%
\usepackage{lmodern}               %para codificaciones vectoriales T1 en vez de bitmap%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                  %para poder copiar texto desde pdf con tildes%
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}                                         %tildes sin código%
\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}                             %idiomas y cuadro->tabla%
\usepackage{anyfontsize}                                     %cualquier tamaño de letra%
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%

%-----------------------------Márgenes modificados-------------------------------------%
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\setlength\oddsidemargin{\dimexpr(\paperwidth-\textwidth)/2 - 1in\relax}  %Para márgenes
                                                 %laterales iguales en twoside document%
\setlength\evensidemargin{\oddsidemargin}
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%

%--------------------------------Paquetes matemáticos----------------------------------%
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,amsmath}        %librerías matemáticas, símbolos y fuentes%
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%

%----------------------------Paquetes gráficos y figuras-------------------------------%
\usepackage{graphicx}                                                         %gráficos%
%\usepackage{subfigure}                                                     %subfiguras%
\usepackage{float}                              %colocar figuras en posición arbitraria%
\usepackage{calc}                                             %imagenes vectoriales svg%
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%

%----------------------------Paquetes estilo y color-----------------------------------%
\usepackage[svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}                               %Paquetes de color%
\usepackage{color}
                                                %colores por nombre en archivo y tablas%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}                                       %cabeceras y pies de página%
\usepackage{fancybox}                           %cajas para parrafos, paginas, ecn, etc%
\usepackage{titlesec}                                       %cambia estilo de capítulos%
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%

%--------------Paquetes manipulación(tablas, listas, hipervínculos...)-----------------%
\usepackage{enumitem}                                    %%listas identadas y numeradas%
\usepackage{nicematrix}                % Paquete bonito para tablas, arreglos y figuras%
\usepackage{tikz}  %Paquete super bonito para dibujar, por ahora auxiliar de nicematrix%
\usepackage{makecell}                %para multirenglones \makerowcell{Parte 1\\Parte2}%
                       % saltos de linea en celdas de tablas \makecell{Parte 1\\Parte2}%
\usepackage{booktabs}                       %Para utilizar comandos de tablas elegantes%
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}                           %Para ajustar altura de tablas%
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=green, bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
                                               %referencias dentro del propio documento%                                         
%======================================================================================%

\begin{document}

Pablito clavó un clavito en la calva de un calvito

\begin{figure}[H]  %It appears correctly
\centering
\def \svgwidth{4cm} 
\input{Mandala1.pdf_tex}
\end{figure}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{figure}[H] %It appears correctly
\centering
\def \svgscale{0.2} 
\input{Mandala1.pdf_tex}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\def \svgscale{0.4} 
\input{images/musica.pdf_tex} %It doesn't appear -> Error
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Part of log file:

```
...
File: uni-0.def 2013/05/13 UCS: Unicode data U+0000..U+00FF
)
(Mandala1.pdf_tex
<Mandala1.pdf, id=6, page=1, 623.32722pt x 622.83313pt>
File: Mandala1.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use Mandala1.pdf, page 1>
Package pdftex.def Info: Mandala1.pdf , page1 used on input line 56.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 113.81102pt x 113.72073pt.
) (Mandala1.pdf_tex
File: Mandala1.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use Mandala1.pdf, page 1>
Package pdftex.def Info: Mandala1.pdf , page1 used on input line 56.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 124.66353pt x 124.5644pt.
) (images/musica.pdf_tex

LaTeX Warning: File `musica.pdf' not found on input line 56.


! Package pdftex.def Error: File `musica.pdf' not found: using draft setting.
1
See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.56 ...ics[width=\unitlength,page=1]{musica.pdf}}
                                                  %
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
...
```

Comment: You can have a look at [tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139401/how-to-use-graphicspath](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139401/how-to-use-graphicspath)

Comment: You could try `\usepackage{import}` and then use `\import{images}{musica.pdf_tex}` instead of `\input`.

Comment: @Skillmonlikestopanswers.xyz, thanks for your help!! I tried the ```import``` option before, but I was doing it wrong. Thanks, again :D If you put this as an answer, I'll mark it as a solution :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to include a file which in turn includes other files with relative paths, you can use the `import` package and either `\import` or `\subimport`. In your example you would use

```
\usepackage{import}
...
\import{images}{musica.pdf_tex}
```

instead of

```
\input{images/musica.pdf_tex}
```