# How to set \input global directory to \graphicspath?

Tags: templates, input, directory

tI have Latex template to which I pass parameters using Pandoc. One parameter is $logopath$ where all the graphics are located and I'm able to set graphicspath properly, no problem.

```
\graphicspath{{$logopath$}} % this works
```

I decided to break my main template into parts so that I can load only necessary packages and contents from subtemplates and by doing that, I simplify my main template structure. When I use absolute path, input works as expected.

```
\input{/Users/pasi/Projects/dxss/endusers/a/sub1.tex} % this works
```

Since these templates are distributed to various systems and locations, it is mandatory to use same information as I have in graphicspath. Main template, subtemplates and graphics files are in the same directory and I can't "hard code" the absolute path. I recognize that [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79058/can-a-default-path-be-set-globally-for-input-akin-to-graphicspath) question/answer looks like a 100 % match, but I'm not able to make it work no matter what...

```
\makeatletter
\def\input@path{{$logopath$}} % this doesn't work
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\def\input@path{{/Users/pasi/Projects/dxss/endusers/a/}} % this works
\makeatother
```

When I try this:

```
\input{sub1.tex}
```

It fails, as all other variations except absolute paths.

**UPDATE**.

I just realized that my Projects directory is a symbolic link to "Machintosh HD 2/Projects". Somehow \graphicspath seems to accept path with white spaces, but \input@path doesn't. My program that passes $logopath$ variable to Pandoc inserts true path into that variable, not path with a symbolic link. White spaces are escaped.

Bug or feature with \input?

Comment: using absolute paths within the document is usually discouraged as it makes them non portable, it isn't clear what kind of parameter `$logopath$` is (an environment variable or something pandoc inserts into the tex file or ...) nor do you say what value it has) but if you add `/Users/pasi/Projects/dxss//` to your TEXINPUTS enviornment variable or web2c config file settings, then `\input` and `\includegraphics` should find any file in any directory below that if just used as `\input{sub1}`  or `\includegraphics{mypic2}` etc

Comment: $logopath$ is just an shell escaped string that includes the directory name where graphics are located.

Comment: But how is it communicated to tex? via setting an environment or by inserting something into the tex document? and does it include a trailing `/` as required for graphicspath

Comment: I pass $logopath$ to tex as Pandoc --variable and yes, it includes / plus as said, graphicspath works just fine.

Comment: if graphicspath works I can't see why the input@path definition you give wouldn't work as it is the same thing, that is you are defining `input@path` to be `{{/Users/pasi/Projects/dxss/endusers/a/}}` ?

Comment: That is exactly the problem. It works, when I add absolute path to input@path - if I add $graphicspath$, \graphicspath, graphicspath{{$logopath}}, $logopath$ or any (hopeless) variant, it doesn't.

Comment: what does "not work" mean, what is in the actual latex file that is passed to latex after pandoc has done its variable substitutions, and what error do you get?

Comment: Don't work means that it can't find the file.

Comment: you say `\def\input@path{/Users/pasi/Projects/dxss/endusers/a/} % this works` works but that should not work, the syntax should be `\def\input@path{{/Users/pasi/Projects/dxss/endusers/a/}} % this works` with two `{{` and if that form works then `\def\input@path{{$logopath$}}` should be identical input to tex after pandoc has replaced `$logopath$` by `/Users/pasi/Projects/dxss/endusers/a/`

Comment: My bad, mistake with copy-paste - I copied a non-working example - edited the original respectively.

Comment: if pandoc replaces `$logopath$` by `/Users/pasi/Projects/dxss/endusers/a/` then the input to latex is the same so both should work. If if does not do the replacement then why not? (and that is presumably a pandoc question rather than a tex one, I don't have pandoc to test)

Comment: I guess I may have found the root cause. I just realized that my Projects-directory is a symbolic link to "Macintosh HD 2/Projects". Somehow graphicspath works as expected, but input doesn't. Possibly the spaces in string cause this problem, even though they're escaped...

Answer (score 2):

I would have never guessed that this works...

```
\makeatletter
\def\input@path{{"$logopath$"}} % working solution with possible white spaces in path
\makeatother
```

This "quoting" also seems to work with paths without white spaces. Big thanks to @David Carlisle for your comments. Glorious win for trial-n-error -method :)