\graphicspath but for tables
I want to do something similar to this post Separate directory for tables
I want to have a standard directory path for tables like I have it for figures. For figures, I have the following:
\graphicspath{ {./files/}} % standard path for figures

And LaTeX just looks for jpg files in this path if I do not define another path.
What is a solution to this?

The solution is given in the answers to the question you have already linked to. If these answers are not useful, you need to tell and show your problem with these answers. Otherwise your question is just a duplicate.

BTW: For tables the tag includegraphics is not really useful. Or are your tables images and you want to read them using \includegraphics?

The author of this code said "This is a quick hack, nothing fully reliable, due lack of time".
It works in principle, but hopefully there is a 'default' method today, 8 years later.

There is more than one answer. And do you have a real problem with the hack?

Other related questions: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/220756/277964 https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/241828/277964 … and IMHO the 2 tops: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4602/277964 https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79058/277964
