# using subfiles package and input at the same time

Tags: input, subfiles

I want to call some files in folders.
So I have 3 files :
1. main.tex (in the root)
2. commands.tex (in ./chapters)
3. control1.tex (in ./chapters)
These files contains below codes:
main:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\input{chapters/commands}

\begin{document}

\subfile{./chapters/control1.tex}

\end{document}
```

commands:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

control1:

```
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Control }
\section{intro}
some text
\end{document}
```

When I run main.tex everything looks good and without error.
But if I run control1.tex I got this error:

[image]

It should be mentioned that without commands it runs perfect.
What should I do?
My goal is to put commands line in separate file.

Comment: Why not `\include{filename}`? That's what I placed in my university's thesis template to insert parts into the document.

Comment: Include can not solve my problem. With subfile you should run all file included in main, alone.

Comment: (should*- -> can)

Comment: I had the same problem, and I resolved keeping the main.tex file and all the chapters.tex files in the same folder - in this way the relative path is the same for every file, and `\input` should work properly. Otherwise, you may want to try the solution given in this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79060/74960

Comment: @MarcoG Thanks for the suggestion 

Answer (score 2):

I am just turning my comment into  an answer, since it solved OP's issue.

The problem is that when the file in `./chapters` folder is compiled, it cannot find a file in folder `./chapters/commands.tex`, since this is the path relative to `main.tex` file.                                                                                         I had the same problem while organising the files for my thesis: the easiest solution is to keep all the `subfiles` and the `main` file in the same directory - in this way the relative path is the same for every file, and `\input` should work properly.

If this is not possible, one may want to try the solution given in this answer by Heiko Oberdiek: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79060/74960 .

Answer (score 0):

If using  `\subfile` one has to set the subfile up as

```
\documentclass[../main.tex]{introduction}
\begin{document}
  % content The first line is needed, for the compiler
  % This way it knows where the main.tex lays.
  % The subfile does not require any header.
  % introduction.tex uses the main.tex header
\end{document}
```

in `main.tex` include it as `\subfile{Subfiles/01_introduction/introduction}`

+This way one can compile from within the subfile, because the dependencies are explicit.
I suggest that, because this way one can achieve clarity.

One could use a single folder per chapter containing all additional information regarding that chapter such as photos or graphs, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to not inherit the document class and settings of `main.tex` in `./chapters/control1.tex`.Instead you can define the documentclass and preamble in `control1.tex` itself.
In file `chapter/control1.tex` instead of inheriting(1st line):

```latex
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Control }
\section{intro}
some text
\end{document}
```

Change it to:

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{subfiles}

%rest is same
\begin{document}
\chapter{Control }
\section{intro}
some text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Thanks @Mensch !!