# Default location for input

Tags: include, subfiles

I have file structure that looks like this:

```
images/
    1.png
    2.png
    3.png
photos/
    1.jpg
    2.jpg
    3.jpg
self/
    chapter1.tex
    chapter2.tex
    chapter3.tex
copied/
    chapter1.tex
    chapter2.tex
    chapter3.tex
main.tex
```

(and few other files, but that's not important here).
Now I want to include those images and chapters inside `main.tex`, however I have a lot more than just 3 and I have been wondering if there is a way to specify default location to look into. As I am using `graphix` package, i have `\graphicspath{{images/}{photos/}}` for images, but is there something similar for content files as well?

EDIT: Change file structure to have content files divided into multiple folders

Answer (score 2):

You could simply define a new command for this:

```
\def\contentinput#1{\input{content/#1}}
```

Then

```
\contentinput{chapter1.tex}
```

will include the content of `content/chapter1.tex`.

If you want to have the same functionality as with `\graphicspath` (i.e., providing multiple paths), see [Can a default path be set globally for \input{...} akin to \graphicspath{...}?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79058/can-a-default-path-be-set-globally-for-input-akin-to-graphicspath).

Comment: This works, however, if I have multiple subfolders with content, I'd have to create a separate command for each one, while with `\graphicspath` I can specify more folders. Is there a way around that?

Comment: Sorry, but your question doesn't say so -- on the contrary, it's quite explicitly about one location. So please edit it so that gets clear.

Comment: @RedstoneTehnik you can create a command with two arguments (first optional if you want) like: `\newcommand\myinput[2][content]{\input{#1/#2}}` and then use `\myinput{chapter1.tex}` or `\myinput[content/extracont]{extra.tex}`

Comment: I've added a link to another question that's a duplicate, I think, and has an answer.