# How to include files from a directory specified by a concatenation of text and a macro?

Tags: macros, input

This is almost certainly a silly mistake somewhere. I'm essentially trying to do what is being done [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60147/30469). My MWE project:

```
$ find ./
./
./common
./common/preambleCommon.tex
./mydoc
./mydoc/mydoc.tex
```

mydoc.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
                                       %
\newcommand*{\commonDir}{../common/}%  %
\input{\commonDir{preambleCommon}}     %
                                       %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

Hello!

\mytestcmd

\end{document}
```

preambleCommon.tex:

```
\newcommand*{\mytestcmd}{Hello, from my test cmd.}
```

When I run `latex mydoc.tex`, this comes up:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `../common/preambleCommon.tex' not found.
```

But if I do `ls ../common/preambleCommon.tex` it shows up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message of LaTeX is wrong, it should read:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `../common/{preambleCommon}.tex' not found.
```

The the error is clear: the curly braces. They are not removed as argument braces, because `\commonDir` does not take an argument in `\input{\commonDir{preambleCommon}}`.

Corrected:

```
\newcommand*{\commonDir}{../common/}%
\input{\commonDir preambleCommon}% space is automatically gobbled after command name
```

Comment: I did read the space gobbling but forgot about it ... thanks!