# compile both one-sided and two-sided version of my document by a single typestting

Tags: compiling

I use Book class to compile a journal and need to prepare both one-sided and two-sided versions of the journal which have different settings (margins, ...). Each time I make a change in my TeX file, I have to apply the change to both versions.

Is there any way to typeset both versions by a single file and a single click?

Comment: your question is very similar to [Two pdf versions from one single .TEX file?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173532)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should only have the text in one file.

file `a.tex` can be

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\input{mainfile}
```

file `b.tex` can be

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\input{mainfile}
```

then any text changes just need to be made once in `mainfile.tex` or files that it includes.

You mention 'single click', that depends on the IDE you are using, you could set up a command that typesets both documents in most, although personally I wouldn't. You presumably only need one version until final edits are done.