# Is there a way to output a beamer presentation both with and without the "handout" option, in one run?

Tags: beamer, compiling

Each time I update my lecture slides I have to remember to compile the overlay version (for me to aid my presentation) as well as a handout version (for the students to print and take notes on). Right now, I manually add or remove the "handout" options, i.e. I use

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
```

for handouts and

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
```

for overlays.

Can I just get the LaTeX compiler to do both in one run?

Comment: Welcome to the site! I'd use `arara` for this, as detailed in a similar question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173532/two-pdf-versions-from-one-single-tex-file Maybe a duplicate?...

Comment: You could also create a separate file, say called `notes-handout.tex` and put in it `\PassOptionsToClass{handout}{beamer}\input{notes.tex}` and then write a script to compile both files