# Generating two pdf versions (based on conditional statement) from same tex file with arara

Tags: conditionals, arara

I teach university courses and my goal is to be able to output two `pdf`'s from the same `tex` file:

1. A problem set
2. A problem set with solutions

I already do this manually by calling `\newif` and then setting `\soltrue` or `\solfalse` in the header depending on whether I want to output solutions or not. Then I surround the solutions in `\ifsol` and `\fi` and we're off to the races. It's great because edits to the problem set require changes to only one document, not two. The only annoyance is that I have to compile it once, change that `pdf`'s name, then change the header from `\soltrue` to `\solfalse`, then recompile again to get both documents. I'd like to use `arara` to automate this.

I've been following this excellent [how-to](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/173610/12991) on creating a `yaml` rule to get `arara` to do what I want. In the how-to, the author (cmhughes) creates a rule to compile a `tex` document into two `pdf`'s, one with one column and the other with two. Obviously my application is slightly different.

I have created the following `solutions.yaml` rule:

```
!config
# Make two versions of document depending on if statement "sol"
# author: Shane Auerbach (based on work by Chris Hughes)
# requires arara 3.0+
#
# Sample usage
#
# % arara: solutions
# % arara: solutions: {solutions: true}
# % arara: solutions: {solutions: false}
#
identifier: solutions
name: Solutions
commands: 
- <arara> pdflatex "\newif\ifsol\sol@{trigger}\input{@{file}}" 
- <arara> @{ isWindows( "cmd /c move", "mv" ) } @{getBasename(file)}.pdf @{getBasename(file)}@{trigger.toUpperCase()}.pdf
arguments: 
- identifier: trigger
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.trigger}
  default: false
```

And this is the test `mytex.tex` file:

```
% arara: solutions:  {trigger: true}
% arara: solutions: {trigger: false}

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Question: What is $2+2$?
\ifsol \begin{quote} \textbf{Solution:} $2+2=3$ \end{quote} \fi
\end{document}
```

It works great. When I run `arara` on the `tex` file, it outputs two `pdf`'s, one with the solution and one without, as desired. There are two improvements I would like to make but do not know how to implement:

1. As is, I can currently only compile the `tex` file with `arara` as the file itself has neither `\soltrue` nor `\solfalse` in it. I would like to be able to put in something that set it if and only if it was not already set by `arara` so that I could compile this outside of `arara` also. But I do not want it to overwrite `arara`'s setting, as this would defeat the purpose. Any ideas?
2. Currently the `pdf` files generated are called `mytexTRUE.pdf` (with solutions) and `mytexFALSE.pdf` (without solutions). I'd prefer to have something like `mytexS.pdf` (with solutions) and `mytexQ.pdf` (without solutions). The only way I could think to implement this would be a conditional statement in `solutions.yaml`, but from what I've read `yaml` is not really designed for conditional statements. Any ideas on this front?

If you've read this far, you're a true hero. Thanks! If you skipped the middle, tl;dr: help this stranger make his workflow ever-so-slightly more efficient.

Comment: Hello! Sorry for missing your question earlier! I will come up with some suggestions for improvements later on. Version 4.0 of `arara` might have some goodies for this case, but since it's not officially released (it's in the works), I will write a compatible solution for version 3.0 as well. `:)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A possible way to achieve the first improvement is by exploiting `\ifdefined` instead of relying on a `\newif`, as in the original code. Let us see the new TeX code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Question: What is $2+2$?
\ifdefined\solutionflag\begin{quote} \textbf{Solution:} $2+2=3$ \end{quote}\fi
\end{document}
```

The plan here is straightforward: if `\solutionflag` is defined, that particular code excerpt will be processed. The idea is very similar to using `\if<flag>`, but it does not complain if this contraption isn't set. `:)`

The previous code can be normally compiled with your favourite engine and does not require `arara`. If you want to print the answers, just write `\def\solutionflag{}` somewhere in the preamble and we are done.

**Update:** this answer is updated with a rule for version 4.0+. Check the edit history for and older version.

Let us take a look at this improved rule:

```
!config
identifier: solutions
name: Solutions
authors:
- A duck
commands:
- name: The engine
  command: >
    @{
        prefix = isTrue(solutions, '\\def\\solutionflag{}', '');
        input = '\\input{' + reference.getName() + '}';
        return getCommand(engine, prefix + input, options);
    }
- name: The renaming procedure
  command: >
    @{
        separator = java.io.File.separator;
        prefix = [];
        if (isUnix()) {
            prefix = [ 'mv' ];
        }
        else {
            prefix = [ 'cmd', '/c', 'move' ];
        }
        parent = reference.getParent(); 
        input = parent + separator + getBasename(reference) + '.pdf';
        output = parent + separator + name + '.pdf';
        return getCommand(prefix, input, output);
    }
arguments:
- identifier: engine
  flag: >
    @{
        if ([ 'pdflatex', 'latex', 'xelatex',
              'lualatex' ].contains(parameters.engine)) {
            return parameters.engine;
        }
        else {
            throwError('The provided engine is not valid');
        }
    }
  default: pdflatex
- identifier: name
  flag: >
    @{
        return parameters.name;
    }
  required: true
- identifier: solutions
  flag: >
    @{
        return isTrue(parameters.solutions);
    }
  default: >
    @{
        return false
    }
- identifier: options
  flag: >
    @{
        if (isList(parameters.options)) {
            return parameters.options;
        }
        else {
            throwError('I was expecting a list of options.');
        }
    }
```

The rule arguments:

- `engine`: string, optional, sets the engine. Possible options are `pdflatex`, `latex`, `xelatex` and `lualatex`. Default: `pdflatex`.
- `solutions`: natural boolean, optional, sets whether the solution macro will be defined in the document scope. Default: `false`.
- `name`: string, required, sets the document name. The document will be renamed to this value. No need to specify the `.pdf` extension.
- `options`: list, optional, sets the list of additional command line parameters to be provided to the engine.

A sample execution:

```
% arara: solutions: { solutions: true, name: 'answers' }
% arara: solutions: { solutions: false, name: 'questions' }

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Question: What is $2+2$?
\ifdefined\solutionflag\begin{quote} \textbf{Solution:} $2+2=3$ \end{quote}\fi
\end{document}
```

When running it with `arara`:

```
[paulo@cambridge ~] $ $ arara test.tex 
  __ _ _ __ __ _ _ __ __ _ 
 / _` | '__/ _` | '__/ _` |
| (_| | | | (_| | | | (_| |
 \__,_|_|  \__,_|_|  \__,_|

Processing 'test.tex' (size: 264 bytes, last modified: 03/22/2020
06:54:54), please wait.

(Solutions) The engine .................................. SUCCESS
(Solutions) The renaming procedure ...................... SUCCESS
(Solutions) The engine .................................. SUCCESS
(Solutions) The renaming procedure ...................... SUCCESS

Total: 1.25 seconds
```

We get the following output:

```
[paulo@cambridge ~] $ ls *.pdf
answers.pdf  questions.pdf
```

Another interesting suggestion is to improve your document semantics by creating an environment to selectively display solutions. The following code was kindly suggested by David Carlisle (I owe him $5):

```
\newenvironment{solution}{\ifdefined\solutionflag\else\setbox0\vbox\fi\bgroup}{‌​\par\egroup}
```

Hope it helps! `:)`

Comment: This is fantastic -- thank you, Paulo, for arara and your support of its users!

Comment: @Shane: My pleasure, I am at your service. `:)`