# How to automatically create 4:3 AND 16:9 versions of my LaTeX Beamer slides?

Tags: beamer, pdftex

As someone who often gives talks abroad, I usually do not know beforehand which resolutions the projector supports. Thus, I always create both a 4:3 and a 16:9 version of my slides, using e.g.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
```

Is there a way to create both without having to change this line? I use pdflatex.

Comment: since I use pandoc to generate latex anyway, personally I would just add a pandoc template variable in a custom template... and write a two-line bash file to run once `pandoc -t latex -V aspectratio=169` and once `pandoc -t latex -V aspectratio=43` but that's just me I gues...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If the body of your talk is in `talk.tex` then you just need

**talk43.tex**

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=43]{beamer}\input{talk}
```

**talk169.tex**

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}\input{talk}
```

then use a commandline of

```
pdflatex talk43;pdflatex talk169
```

Comment: Does this mean you need two separate complete copies of the talk?

Comment: @AaronHall no that's the whole point, you just need one copy, `talk.tex`

Comment: Is my edit correct, then?

Comment: @AaronHall no, why add `.tex` to the input? It's never needed.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: [Playing Devil's advocate] Why not add `.tex` to the input? It is never harmful :-)

Comment: @Aditya well a no one ever does it and it's a bad habit to do it unthinkingly as for example if you try it with `\include` it doesn't work at all.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Fair point. Should I submit a bugfix to correct `\include` :-)

Answer (score 10):

Referencing [Two pdf versions from one single .TEX file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173532/two-pdf-versions-from-one-single-tex-file), you can use, for example:

```
\ifdefined\aspectRatio
\else
    \def\aspectRatio{169}
\fi
\documentclass[aspectratio=\aspectRatio]{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\lipsum[1]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and then, assuming your file is `beamer-test.tex` run either of the following commands:

```
pdflatex beamer-test
pdflatex "\def\aspectRatio{43}\input{beamer-test.tex}"
pdflatex "\def\aspectRatio{169}\input{beamer-test.tex}"
```

You can automate the pdf naming convention by using `arara`, as I detailed in my answer to the post above.

See also, for example,

- [Can one TeX file output to multiple PDF files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5228/can-one-tex-file-output-to-multiple-pdf-files)
- [Multiple PDF generation with one tex file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162042/multiple-pdf-generation-with-one-tex-file)

Comment: But you will get only one PDF, beamer-test.pdf, with the last aspect ratio defined. Unfortunately, setting `\jobname` to something different, eg using `\aspectRatio` has no effect. But one could rename `beamer-test.pdf` in between two `pdflatex` calls within a shell script.

Comment: @AlexG hence my link to my previous answer using `arara` :) run `arara` once, get two difference `pdf` files

Comment: Ah, I see. Alright, sorry for the noise.