# change code according to Beamer 'aspectratio'

Tags: beamer, line-breaking

I already search for `beamer`and `aspectratio`.  I have found [How to automatically create 4:3 AND 16:9 versions of my LaTeX Beamer slides?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324355/how-to-automatically-create-43-and-169-versions-of-my-latex-beamer-slides), which comes near to my problem, but does not solve it.

I sometimes do have to switch back to an old device with 4:3 aspect ratio.  It is no problem, to change the `aspectratio` switch in my document preamble and rerun LaTeX.  While this gives me adequate slides in 98 % of the time, there are some slides, which get overfull \hbox errors.

Is there a way to get around this problem, by having two different LaTeX code blocks, one which is choosen, if the `aspectratio` is given as `=169` and one, when it is defined as `=43`?

Something like

```
\ifx{aspectratio}{43}
   code special to\\
   this ratio
\else
   normal code with longer lines
\fi
```

would help a lot.

Comment: You can easily define your own bool command e.g. with etoolbox.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe as a workaround:

```
\newcommand{\aspectratio}{43}
%\newcommand{\aspectratio}{169}
\documentclass[aspectratio=\aspectratio]{beamer}

\begin{document}
test 

\ifnum\aspectratio=169 %
    foo
\else
    bar
\fi

\end{document}
```

---

With the [current beamer development version](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/33672c652c12d7880360ddaa6f7d948285e609d0) (which should be included in beamer v3.70 or newer), one can now use the `\insertaspectratio` macro to access the aspect ratio of the presentation:

```
\documentclass[
    aspectratio=169
%   aspectratio=43
]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\ifnum\insertaspectratio=169
  do something
\else
  something else
\fi
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```