# Automatically producing Beamer handout

Tags: beamer, presentations, handout

I'd like to know if there is a way to automize this process. When writing the slides for my course I create a version to be displayed in class (with pause etc.), then I copy the content of my beamer presentation adding the handout option at the begin to be uploaded to the students (and save same paper).

A. Normal presentation: `\documentclass{beamer}`

B. Handout presentation: `\documentclass[handout]{beamer}`

Is there a way to automize these 2 steps? When I compile the normal presentation (A.), I want LaTeX to automatically produce a handout version (B.) too (and put it in a folder named "Handout"), besides the classical PDF output.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324355/how-to-automatically-create-43-and-169-versions-of-my-latex-beamer-slides