# How to run multiple compilations of a document with different CSV input files

Tags: tables, compiling, pgfplotstable, csv

I have the following document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable, booktabs}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}

\pgfplotstabletypeset [
    col sep = comma,
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule, after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
    display columns/0/.style={string type}
    ]{csv1.csv}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

It uses a separate file, csv1.csv, as input to produce a table:

```
Name,Number
Daniel,1
Mary,2
Sarah,3
```

Suppose I have hundreds of CSV-files and I want to compile one PDF for each of them. The only thing I would need to change in my document is `csv1.csv`.

Comment: I think it'd be easier to compile one table per page (assuming they all fit), then split the resulting PDF in single pages with an external tool.

Comment: @Alenanno - I could do that,  but then I would need to duplicate 99% of the code one time per CSV. I would prefer to duplicate as little as possible for easier maintenance.

Comment: You wouldn't need to duplicate anything, actually.

Comment: Oh, cool - I'm pretty new to LaTeX, so I must have misunderstood something in that case. Perhaps you could post it as an answer with an example?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming that your `.tex` file is called `mytable.tex`, and looks like this:

```
\ifdefined\mycsvfile
\else
    \def\mycsvfile{csv1.csv}
\fi
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable, booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}

\pgfplotstabletypeset [
    col sep = comma,
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule, after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
    display columns/0/.style={string type}
    ]{\mycsvfile}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

then you could use the following (Windows) batch file, `bulkpdfs.bat`

```sh
echo off

echo "batch compiling pdf files"
for %%f in (*.csv) do (
    echo compiling %%f ...
    pdflatex \def\mycsvfile{%%f}\input{mytable.tex} & copy mytable.pdf mytable%%~nf.pdf
)

pause
```

This will produce `mytablecsv1.pdf`, `mytablecsv2.pdf`, ...

For reference, see [Two pdf versions from one single .TEX file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173532/two-pdf-versions-from-one-single-tex-file)

Comment: Gosh, now I feel like an idiot. I was so stuck on trying to find a solution within LaTeX that I neglected to consider the command-line. I'm on OS X, so I guess I can do the same with `xargs`.

Comment: @Leif yes, indeed; I'm working on Windows at the moment, and can't test an `xargs` solution, but it would be something like `find -name *.csv -print0|xargs -0 pdflatex....`

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if the code above is a short example or the actual document (from your wording I assume it's the actual one).

If you have multiple `csv` files — which for this solution must be named with the format `csv#.csv`, where `#` is a number — and if the tables all fit one single page without any particular problems, then you can use a loop to typeset them one per page. This answer shows an example of that, but of course, actual application might vary depending on the size of the tables.

### Output (single pages)

**1** [image]   
**2** [image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable, booktabs}
\usepackage{filecontents}% just for this example
\usepackage{geometry}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

% These two are just for this example. You should have external files anyway.
\begin{filecontents*}{csv1.csv}
Name,Number
Daniel,1
Mary,2
Sarah,3
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{csv2.csv}
Name,Number
Jack,24
John,5
Matthew,32
\end{filecontents*}
%%%
\begin{document}
\foreach \x in {1,2}{% <-- if you have many csv, you can say e.g. {1,...,45}
    \pgfplotstabletypeset [
        col sep = comma,
        every head row/.style={before row=\toprule, after row=\midrule},
        every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
        display columns/0/.style={string type}
        ]{csv\x.csv}%
    \newpage
}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this answer. I didn't know it was possible to create `foreach` looks in LaTeX like that. I accepted the other answer because it outputs separate PDFs and fits better to the problem at hand, but I learned something valuable from your answer also, so thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Here one way how you can do it:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable, booktabs}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

% Create your own command 
\newcommand\MyTable[1]{\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    col sep = comma,
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule, after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
    display columns/0/.style={string type}
    ]{#1.csv}\newpage
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}

\MyTable{csv1}
\MyTable{csv2}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is beautiful - I didn't know it was possible to create new commands with parameters like that. I accepted the other answer because it fits better what I'm trying to achieve right now, but I learned a lot from this answer also, so thank you.