# create 2 pdfs in 2 folders from one main.tex

Tags: pdf

How can i create 2 pdf files (Output01.pdf and Main.pdf) from one main.tex?

Output01.pdf in Folder Ouput

And

Main.pdf in same Forder with main.tex

Example my main.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello world
\end{document}
```

Thank in advance

Comment: From the very same TeX code? Then using `-jobname=Output01` or `-jobname=Main` in the compilation command for `main.tex` should do the trick. If this doesn't work, try with two dashes: `--jobname`.

Comment: there have been a few questions on this previously. for example, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173532/two-pdf-versions-from-one-single-tex-file?noredirect=1&lq=1