# Latex, Tikz, PDF's and Multiple .tex files

Tags: tikz-pgf, input, include

To give a brief background of my situation, I am currently writing a group report in LaTeX for my honours project and I'm attempting to use LaTeX for this. There are several sections in this report, each in different .tex files, each contributed by different people and there is also a document class that has been provided to us. Below is an example of the file structure:

Master Tex file:

```
- section 1
--Images
--TikzInput
--IncludePDFs
- section 2
--Images
--TikzInput
--IncludePDFs
etc..
```

Each document (section) complies perfectly fine by itself, including input PDF's and input tikz files. When I attempt to bring them together in a master document using `\include` or `\input`, the document looks for the tikz input files and the IncludePDFs files in the master tex location. I've currently found a way to include different paths for the image folders, is there a similar way for tikz scripts/pdfs?

alternatively, is there a way to separately compile each section by themselves and then compile them together at the end?

Currently, the only way i can see to do this is to manual change the paths before compiling them all together which is rather arduous for an 400 page document, even with ctrl-f.

Thanks in advance for anyone thoughts/input.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Relevant/possible duplciate: [Path to External Files in Nested \input](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60135/path-to-external-files-in-nested-input)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `import` package from the site CTAN:

http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/import/import.pdf