# 'classicthesis-config.tex' not found

Tags: lyx, classicthesis

I'm trying to make Classic Thesis work with Lyx. I downloaded the package, unzipped it, and opened ClassicThesis.lyx. So far, so good, but when I try to compile it, I get the following error message:

> LaTeX Error: File `classicthesis-config.tex' not found.
>
> Description:
>
> \input{classicthesis-config.tex}
>
> *** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)

The classicthesis-config.tex file is right there with the other files from the template, so I don't what I'm doing wrong. Do I need to put it somewhere else before using the template?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't come when you download the package. however, you can get this file plus a host of other ones, all of which can be reused and configured to your liking. Download the files in a folder wherever you want (not necessarily the LaTeX folders) so that you can find it easily.
https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis/

Enjoy!!!

Answer (score 0):

where is the `\include` command ? in the body of the file, in the preamble ?
make sure it is defined well, that the path of the command points to where the file is...

check this thread out
[Path to External Files in Nested \input](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60135/path-to-external-files-in-nested-input)