# How to avoid name conflicts (different directories) using the `import` package

Tags: pdftex, input, nesting, import, directory

I want to provide some structure for my thesis source files. I decided to use nested directories. Every directory contains `main.tex` index file to be imported by a file in the parent directory.

From [Path to External Files in Nested \input](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60135/path-to-external-files-in-nested-input) I learned about `import` package, however it is not working for me.

For the simplest case

```
/
+- main.tex: |\documentclass{report}
|            |\usepackage{import}
|            |\begin{document}
|            |main
|            |
|            |\subimport{a}{main.tex}
|            |\end{document}
+- a/
    +- main.tex: |a main
```

I expect to have result like:

```
main

a main
```

Instead, I get the following error during compilation:

```
$ pdflatex main
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9h> and hyphenation patterns for 5 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls
Document Class: report 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/import/import.sty) (./main.aux)
(./main.tex

! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1 \documentclass
                  {report}
```

`\subimport{a}{main}` nor `\subimport{a/}{main}` neither works.

How can I tell the `import` package not to look for import files in the root directory? Also I wonder, if the issue won't occur in subdirectories too (at the moment I was unable to cause it).

Comment: The best way is to have unique names ...

Comment: why use `\import` at all? just use `\input{a/main}` but i see no advantage in giving multiple files the same name.

Comment: @Zarko: names are unique within a directory

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: imagine length of a path for file in sub-sub-subdirectory, all directories with meaningful names. Then imagine that for some reason I may want to move/rename one of the directories with minimal effort.

Comment: Anyway you could use nested `\input` commands with relative paths.

Comment: @TeXnician Already tried `\input{b}` (in `/a/a.tex` included in `/main.tex` with `\input{a/a}`) to include `/a/b.tex`. Result: `LaTeX Error: File \`b.tex' not found`

Comment: the input all need to be relative to the working directory

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Just to clarify: you mean the working directory of my commandline, not the directory the file with `\input` file is?

Comment: yes, that's just how tex is.